# Telescopic Parentheses

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, whitespace, balanced-string

Consider a non-empty string of correctly balanced parentheses:

```
(()(()())()((())))(())
```

We can imagine that each pair of parentheses represents a ring in a collapsed [telescopic construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_(mechanics)). So let's extend the telescope:

```
(                )(  )
 ()(    )()(    )  ()
    ()()    (  )
             ()
```

Another way to look at it is that the parentheses at depth *n* are moved to line *n*, while keeping their horizontal position.

Your task is to take such a string of balanced parentheses and produce the extended version.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest equivalent), command-line argument or function parameter, and producing output via STDOUT (or closest equivalent), return value or function (out) parameter.

You may assume that the input string is valid, i.e. consists only parentheses, which are correctly balanced.

You may print trailing spaces on each line, but not any more leading spaces than necessary. In total the lines must not be longer than twice the length of the input string. You may optionally print a single trailing newline.

### Examples

In addition to the above example, here are a few more test cases (input and output are separated by an empty line).

```
()

()
```

```
(((())))

(      )
 (    )
  (  )
   ()
```

```
()(())((()))(())()

()(  )(    )(  )()
   ()  (  )  ()
        ()
```

```
((()())()(()(())()))

(                  )
 (    )()(        )
  ()()    ()(  )()
             ()
```

**Related Challenges:**

- **[Topographic Strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6600/8478)**, which asks you to produce what is essentially the complement of the output in this challenge.
- **[Code Explanation Formatter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49016/8478)**, a broad generalisation of the ideas in this challenge, posted recently by PhiNotPi. (In fact, PhiNotPi's original description of his idea was what inspired this challenge.)

### Leaderboards

Huh, this got quite a lot of participation, so here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items);if(e.has_more)getAnswers();else process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var t=false;var n=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{t|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown);t|=["-","="].indexOf(n[1][0])>-1;t&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(r){}return t}function shouldHaveScore(e){var t=false;try{t|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(n){}return t}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading);answers.sort(function(e,t){var n=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0],r=+(t.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0];return n-r});var e={};var t=0,c=0,p=-1;answers.forEach(function(n){var r=n.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];var i=$("#answer-template").html();var s=r.match(NUMBER_REG)[0];var o=(r.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0];var u=r.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];var a=getAuthorName(n);t++;c=p==o?c:t;i=i.replace("{{PLACE}}",c+".").replace("{{NAME}}",a).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",u).replace("{{SIZE}}",o).replace("{{LINK}}",n.share_link);i=$(i);p=o;$("#answers").append(i);e[u]=e[u]||{lang:u,user:a,size:o,link:n.share_link}});var n=[];for(var r in e)if(e.hasOwnProperty(r))n.push(e[r]);n.sort(function(e,t){if(e.lang>t.lang)return 1;if(e.lang<t.lang)return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<n.length;++i){var s=$("#language-template").html();var r=n[i];s=s.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",r.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",r.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",r.size).replace("{{LINK}}",r.link);s=$(s);$("#languages").append(s)}}var QUESTION_ID=49042;var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;var NUMBER_REG=/\d+/;var LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*([^,]+)/
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id=answer-list><h2>Leaderboard</h2><table class=answer-list><thead><tr><td></td><td>Author<td>Language<td>Size<tbody id=answers></table></div><div id=language-list><h2>Winners by Language</h2><table class=language-list><thead><tr><td>Language<td>User<td>Score<tbody id=languages></table></div><table style=display:none><tbody id=answer-template><tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}<td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table><table style=display:none><tbody id=language-template><tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{NAME}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table>
```

Comment: Alternative title: De-Lisp-ify a string. :P

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the color of the output?

Comment: @MatteoItalia That's a funny question, I never considered that. In general I would probably regard the output as the byte stream of your output, not as what's displayed on screen, so a change of colour will probably indicate that you sent some additional bytes that don't really belong there. But for this question, I'm going to say the colour doesn't matter (unless it's something like black on black, obviously), and will take this to meta.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: nevermind, I found a cleaner way; let's just say that my previous idea would have shaved a byte leaving all the closed parentheses *blinking* blue over cyan... :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia oh god, I'm glad that didn't happen. ;)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Post that version! It's worth seeing.

Comment: @user2357112: that would be the 30 bytes version, but with the first `push`/`pop` restored to the original `mov ax,0b8c3h`/`mov es,ax` and the `lodsw` restored to `lodsb`. IIRC that was 33 bytes, I discarded that possibility because changing the `mov`/`mov` with a `push`/`pop` already produced that gain without the blinking; however then I resorted to some similar trick to shave some other bytes, so we are back to ugly colors (but no blinking `:-(` ).

Comment: If I had this idea on my Math exams, it would be so cool, for not making mistakes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
0000000: 72 3a 69 22 28 0b 20 9b 41 29 22 53 2f 66 3d     r:i"(. .A)"S/f=
```

The above is a reversible xxd dump, since the source code contains the unprintable characters VT (0x0b) and CSI (0x9b).

Like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49118), it uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), but it also uses vertical tabs and it prints the control characters directly to avoid using **printf**.

This requires a supporting video text terminal, which includes most non-Windows terminal emulators.

#### Test run

We have to set the shell variable *LANG* and the terminal emulator's encoding to ISO 8859-1. The former is achieved by executing

```
$ LANGsave="$LANG"
$ LANG=en_US
```

Also, before executing the actual code, we'll disable the prompt and clear the screen.

```
$ PS1save="$PS1"
$ unset PS1
$ clear
```

This makes sure the output is shown properly.

```
echo -n '()(())((()))(())()' | cjam <(base64 -d <<< cjppIigLIJtBKSJTL2Y9)
()(  )(    )(  )()
   ()  (  )  ()
        ()
```

To restore *LANG* and the prompt, execute this:

```
$ LANG="$LANGsave"
$ PS1="$PS1save"
```

#### How it works

We insert a vertical tab after each **(** to move the cursor down and the byte sequence **9b 41** (`"\x9bA"`) before each **)** to move the cursor up.

```
r         e# Read a whitespace-separated token from STDIN.
:i        e# Replace each character by its code point.
          e#   '(' -> 40, ')' -> 41
"(. .A)"  e# Push the string "(\v \x9bA)".
S/        e# Split at spaces into ["(\v" "\x9bA)"].
f=        e# Select the corresponding chunks.
          e# Since arrays wrap around in CJam, ["(\v" "\x9bA)"]40= and 
          e# ["(\v" "\x9bA)"]41= select the first and second chunk, respectively.
```

Answer (score 53):

## x86 machine code, <del>39</del> <del>34</del> <del>33</del> <del>30</del> 29 bytes

```
00000000  68 c3 b8 07 31 ff be 82  00 b3 a0 ad 4e 3c 28 7c  |h...1.......N<(||
00000010  f0 77 05 ab 01 df eb f3  29 df ab eb ee           |.w......)....|
0000001d
```

x86 assembly for DOS, with some tricks:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    ; point the segment ES to video memory
    ; (c3 is chosen so that it doubles as a "ret")
    push 0b8c3h
    pop es
    ; di: output pointer to video memory
    xor di,di
    ; si: input pointer from the command line
    mov si,82h
    ; one row=160 bytes (assume bh=0, as should be)
    mov bl,160
lop:
    ; read & increment si (assume direction flag clean)
    ; we read a whole word, so that later we have something nonzero to
    ; put into character attributes
    lodsw
    ; we read 2 bytes, go back 1
    dec si
    ; check what we read
    cmp al,'('
    ; less than `(`: we got the final `\n` - quit
    ; (we jump mid-instruction to get a c3 i.e. a ret)
    jl start+1
    ; more than `(`: assume we got a `)`
    ja closed
    ; write a whole word (char+attrs), so we end
    ; one position on the right
    stosw
    ; move down
    add di,bx
    ; rinse & repeat
    jmp lop
closed:
    ; move up
    sub di,bx
    ; as above
    stosw
    jmp lop
```

*Limitations*:

- it always prints starting at the bottom of the screen, without erasing first; a `cls` before running is almost mandatory;
- the colors are ugly; that's the consequence of recycling the next character as color attributes to save two bytes here and there;
- the code assumes `bh=0` and the direction flag clear on start, both undocumented; OTOH, `bx` is explicitly set to zero in all DOS variants I saw (DosBox, MS-DOS 2, FreeDOS), and everywhere I tested the flags were already OK.

[image]

Comment: Just verified this. Yes, it works. Are you sure you need to do `cld`?

Comment: @FUZxxl: on DosBox it works fine even without it, but looking at its sources it says that the flags are preserved from whatever happened in DOS and in TRSs before, so probably it would be required to play it safe. Anyhow, that would be just one byte, the real payoff would be to kill at least one of those big (=4 byte each) `add`/`sub`.

Comment: Hm... no idea, really.

Comment: Can you change `lop` to `loop`?

Comment: @mbomb007: maybe? I'm not sure if `nasm` disambiguates between `loop` as a label and `loop` the assembly instruction, so I just write `lop` as everybody else does.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wasn't sure. I suppose it might be possible for the `loop` instruction's opcode to be interpreted as a literal address to jump to?

Comment: @mbomb007: I don't think that any assembler ever did that, the source of confusion are labels, since colons are usually optional; see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/04/16/10607806.aspx) for a more detailed discussion of this exact issue.

Answer (score 29):

### J, <s>32</s> 28 bytes

This was a fun one.

```
0|:')(('&(i.-<:@+/\@i:){."0]
```

#### Explanation

This is how this solution works, including an explanation of how it has been golfed.

```
   NB. Let a be a test case
   a =. '((()())()(()(())()))'

   NB. level alterations
   _1 + ').(' i. a
1 1 1 _1 1 _1 _1 1 _1 1 1 _1 1 1 _1 _1 1 _1 _1 _1

   NB. absolute levels
   +/\ _1 + ').(' i. a
1 2 3 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 2 3 2 1 0

   NB. adjusted levels
   (+/\ _1 + ').(' i. a) - ')(' i. a
0 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 0

   NB. take level from end of each item of a and transpose
   |: a {."0~ _1 - (+/\ _1 + ').(' i. a) - ')(' i. a
(                  )
 (    )()(        ) 
  ()()    ()(  )()  
             ()     

   NB. code as a tacit verb
   [: |: ] {."0~ _1 - ([: +/\ _1 + ').(' i. ]) - ')(' i. ]

   NB. subtractions pulled into the prefix insert
   [: |: ] {."0~ (')(' i. ]) - [: <:@+/\ ').(' i. ]

   NB. i: instead of i. so we can use the same string constant
   [: |: ] {."0~ (')((' i. ]) - [: <:@+/\ ')((' i: ]

   NB. get rid of the caps
   0 |: ] {."0~ (')((' i. ]) - ')((' <:@+/\@i: ]

   NB. join the two usages of ')((' into a single dyadic phrase
   0 |: ] {."0~ ')((' (i. - <:@+/\@i:) ]

   NB. bond ')((' and flip arguments to {."0
   0 |: ')(('&(i. - <:@+/\@i:) {."0 ]
```

Comment: Very nice! The solution is full of great parts!

Comment: (I usually add an example invocation of the function so non-experienced users could try it out too.)

Comment: This solution makes my head hurt `:')`

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I take this as a compliment.

Comment: @FUZxxl It is. It's also a pun based on a sequence of characters that appears in your answer.

Answer (score 17):

## C, 150 bytes

```c
t;f(char*c){char l=strlen(c)+1,o[l*l],*A=o,m=0;for(t=1;t<l*l;t++)o[t-1]=t%l?32:10;for(t=-1;*c;c++)A++[l*(*c-41?++t>m?m=t:t:t--)]=*c;A[m*l]=0;puts(o);}
```

This was *crazy* fun to golf. I'm still not convinced I'm done with it.

We define a single function, `f`, that takes the string as input and outputs to stdout.

Let's go through the code, line by line:

```c
/* t will represent the current depth of a parentheses. It must be an int. */
t;
f(char*c){
    //Our variables:
    char l=strlen(c)+1,    //The length of each row of output, including newlines
         o[l*l],           //The output string. It's way larger than it needs to be.
         *A=o,             //We need another pointer to keep track of things.
         m=0;              //The maximum depth recorded thus far.

    for(t=1;t<l*l;t++)     //For each character in our output...
        o[t-1]=t%l?32:10;  //If it's at the end of a line, make it '\n'. Else, ' '.
    for(t=-1;*c;c++)       //While we have an input string...
        //Perhaps a personal record for ugliest warning-less line...
        A++[l*(*c-41?++t>m?m=t:t:t--)]=*c;
    /* 
        A breakdown:
        A++        --> Go to the next *column* of output, after writing. 
                   --> There will only ever be one parentheses per output column.
        [l*(...)]  --> A[l*X] is the character in the current column at depth X.
        (*c-41?    --> If the character is a '('...    
        ++t>m?     --> Increment t *before* we write it. If this is a new highest depth
        m=t:       --> Set m to t, and set the whole expression to t.
        t:         --> If it's not a new highest depth, don't set m.
        t--)       --> If the character was a ')', decrement t *after* we write it.
        =*c        --> Write our output character to whatever the input read.
    */    
    
    A[m*l]=0; //The last character of the maximum-depth line should be null terminated.
    puts(o);  //Output!
}
```

I'll answer any questions you may have!

Try a test program [online](http://ideone.com/v5nyZ5)!

Comment: I want to remember that "char l=strlen(c)+1, o[l*l]" isn't valid because you can't define a variable sized array like that, but it's been 15 years since I tried anything of that sort in C.

Comment: @Sparr My compiler doesn't even throw a warning. I believe this was "officially" standard in C99. I will try to find a reference for this.

Comment: @Sparr [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) is a reference.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem things changed around 15 (give or take a couple) years ago in this regard :)

Comment: `for(t=0;++t<l*l;)` or `for(t;++t<l*l)`

Comment: This `for(t=l*l;--t;)` should always work (`t` is local and needs to be initialized).

Comment: @f.ardelian `for(t=l*l;--t;)` fails because it tries to access a negative index of `o`. It should be easily modifiable, though. I'll look at this soon.

Comment: @BrainSteel Are you sure the loop executes with a negative index? `--t` decrements and _then_ checks for 0.

Comment: Wouldn't making `m` a global `int` save some bytes?

Comment: @CoolGuy It would, but on subsequent calls of `f`, `m` would not reset to 0. This counts as "breaking your environment," outlawed [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4940/31054).

Answer (score 17):

## Retina + Bash, 27 bytes (14 + 10 + 3 = 27)

This makes use of ANSI Escapes:

```
\(
(\e[B
\)
\e[A)
```

Equivalent to `sed -e "s/(/(\\\e[B/g;s/)/\\\e[A)/g"`.
The `\e[B` escape code means move cursor down one row, and the `\e[A` means move cursor up one row, so this solution simply inserts those codes after and before the start and end of each nested pair of parentheses. Input is passed through STDIN.

You'll have to call it as `printf $(Retina ...)` to see the output correctly.

### Output

```
(((())))
(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)
^C
amans:~ a$ printf "(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)"
(      )amans:~ a$ 
 (    )
  (  )
   ()

((()())()(()(())()))
(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)
^C
amans:~ a$ printf "(\e[B(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)(\e[B(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)(\e[B\e[A)\e[A)\e[A)"
(                  )amans:~ a$ 
 (    )()(        )
  ()()    ()(  )()
             ()
```

Comment: Well, not bad! If you could point to a specific terminal that *doesn't* need `printf` that would be great. Otherwise, I think it would only be fair to add `| printf` to the byte count.

Comment: @MartinBüttner It should be ``printf $()`` or ``printf $(Retina    )``.

Comment: What's that Retina thingy?

Comment: I can't find one which doesn't, so ill add `printf $()` to the count :)

Comment: @FUZxxl It's my own regex-based programming language. [See GitHub](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina).

Comment: Why `\e` plus `printf`? You can simply put the control characters in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 16):

## TI-BASIC, <s>69 60 56</s> 55 bytes

This is for the TI-83+/84+ family of calculators, although it was written on an 84+ C Silver Edition.

The program shows up as larger on-calc due to VAT+size info being included. Also, there are more than 56 characters here; the reason it's 56 bytes is because all commands that are more than one character are compressed down to tokens that are either one or two bytes in size.

```
Input Str1
1→B
For(A,1,length(Str1
sub(Str1,A,1→Str2
Ans="(
Output(B+Ans,A,Str2
B-1+2Ans→B
End
```

Shaved off another byte thanks to [thomas-kwa](http://stackexchange.com/users/5456847/thomas-kwa)! (also from him was the jump from 60 to 56.)

Comment: Ahhh, my first programming language. Thanks for the nostalgia, haha.

Comment: Still programing TI for highschool math class, very useful to have formulas built in that will calculate for you on tests and assignments.

Comment: If you shift things around you can use the `cos(piAns` trick to save another byte.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, 115 bytes

```py
def f(L,n=0,O=()):
 for c in L:n-=c>"(";O+=" "*n+c,;n+=c<")"
 for r in map(None,*O):print"".join(c or" "for c in r)
```

Call like `f("((()())()(()(())()))")`, and output is to STDOUT.

### Explanation

We start with `n = 0`. For each char in the input line:

- If the char is `(`, we prepend `n` spaces then increment `n`
- If the char is `)`, we decrement `n` then prepend `n` spaces

The result is then zipped and printed. Note that Python's `zip` zips to match the length of the *shortest* element, e.g.

```py
>>> zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Usually one would use `itertools.zip_longest` (`izip_longest`) if they wanted `zip` to pad to the length of the *longest* element.

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (None, None, 7)]
```

But in Python 2, this behaviour can be simulated by mapping `None`:

```py
>>> map(None, [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (None, None, 7)]
```

---

### Python 3, 115 bytes

```py
L,d,*O=input(),0
for i,c in enumerate(L):b=c>"(";O+="",;O[d-b]=O[d-b].ljust(i)+c;d-=b*2-1
for l in O:l and print(l)
```

No zipping, just padding appropriately with `ljust`. This one seems to have some golfing potential.

Answer (score 10):

## C, <s>58 53 52 51</s> 49 bytes

Makes use of ANSI escape sequences to move the cursor position.

```
f(char*s){while(*s)printf(*s++&1?"\e[A)":"(\v");}
```

If not using gcc or another compiler that supports `\e` then it can be replaced with `\x1B` for a total of 2 extra bytes. `\e[A` moves the cursor up one row and `\e[B` moves the cursor down one row. It's not necessary to use `\e[B` to move down one row as it's two bytes shorter to use the ASCII vertical tab character `0xB` or `\v`.

The input string is assumed, from the question, to consist of only (balanced) parentheses, so checking the parity of the character, with `&1`, is enough to distinguish between `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 9):

## R, <s>151</s> 127 characters

```
S=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]];C=cumsum;D=c(C(S=="("),0)-c(0,C(S==")"));for(j in 1:max(D)){X=S;X[D!=j]=' ';cat(X,sep='',fill=T)}
```

With indents and newlines:

```r
S=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]]
C=cumsum
D=c(C(S=="("),0)-c(0,C(S==")"))
for(j in 1:max(D)){
    X=S
    X[D!=j]=' '
    cat(X,sep='',fill=T)
    }
```

Usage:

```
> S=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]];C=cumsum;D=c(C(S=="("),0)-c(0,C(S==")"));for(j in 1:max(D)){X=S;X[D!=j]=' ';cat(X,sep='',fill=T)}
1: ()(())((()))(())()
2: 
Read 1 item
()(  )(    )(  )()
   ()  (  )  ()   
        ()        
> S=strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]];C=cumsum;D=c(C(S=="("),0)-c(0,C(S==")"));for(j in 1:max(D)){X=S;X[D!=j]=' ';cat(X,sep='',fill=T)}
1: ((()())()(()(())()))
2: 
Read 1 item
(                  )
 (    )()(        ) 
  ()()    ()(  )()  
             ()
```

It reads the string as stdin, splits it as a vector of single characters, computes the cumulative sum of `(` and `)`, substracts the former with the latter (with a lag) thus computing the "level" of each parentheses. It then prints to stdout, for each level, either the corresponding parentheses or a space.

Thanks to @MickyT for helping me shortening it considerably!

Comment: +1 Nice and elegant solution.  You can save 6 by replacing `for(i in n)cat(ifelse(D[i]-j," ",S[i]));cat("\n")` with `X=S;X[which(D!=j)]=' ';cat(X,sep='',fill=T)`.  Then `n` isn't really required, but you would need change the cumsum part a bit. `D=c(C(S=="("),0)-c(0,C(S==")"));` bringing it down to 135.

Comment: @MickyT wow thanks! didn't thought of that. `which` is not really necessary here though (`D!=j` being already a vector of booleans allowing indexing). I didn't know argument `fill` for `cat`, that's a nifty trick! Thanks for making me shorten it by an astounding 24 characters!!

Answer (score 9):

## Pip, 53 bytes

[**Pip**](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) is a code-golf language of my invention. The first version was published on Saturday, so I can officially take it for a spin! The solution below isn't terribly competitive as golfing languages go, but that's partly because I haven't implemented things like zip and max yet.

```
z:{aEQ'(?++v--v+1}MaW(o:{z@++v=i?as}Ma)RMs{Pov:-1++i}
```

Expects the string of parentheses as a command-line argument.

"Ungolfed" version:

```
z:{
   a EQ '( ?
    ++v
    --v+1
  } M a
W (o:{
      z @ ++v = i ?
       a
       s
     } M a
  ) RM s
{
 P o
 v:-1
 ++i
}
```

**Explanation:**

Unlike most golfing languages, Pip is imperative with infix operators, so the syntax is somewhat closer to C and its derivatives. It also borrows ideas from functional and array-based programming. See the repository for further documentation.

The program first generates a list of depths (storing it in `z`) by mapping a function to the input string `a`. The global variable `v` tracks the current level. (Variables `a-g` in Pip are function-local variables, but `h-z` are global. `v` is handy because it's preinitialized to -1.)

Next, we use a `W`hile loop to generate and print each line, until the line generated would consist of all spaces. `v` is now used for columns, and `i` for rows. The `{z@++v=i?as}` function, repeatedly mapped to the original input string, tests whether the current line `i` matches the line the current parenthesis is supposed to be on (as stored in the `z` list). If so, use the parenthesis (`a`); if not, use `s` (preinitialized to space). The end result is that on each iteration, `o` gets assigned a list of characters equivalent to the next line of the output.

To test whether we should continue looping, we check if `o` with all the spaces `RM`'d is empty. If not, print it (which by default concatenates everything together as in CJam), reset the column number to -1, and increment the row number.

(Fun fact: I had a 51-byte solution at first... which didn't work because it turned up a bug in the interpreter.)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

```
VzJs.e?YqN-/<zk\(/<zhk\)dzI-JdJ
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VzJs.e%3FYqN-%2F%3Czk%5C(%2F%3Czhk%5C)dzI-JdJ&input=(()(()())()((())))(())&debug=0)

`-/<zk\(/<zhk\)`: Finds the appropriate level for the current character position.

`?YqN-/<zk\(/<zhk\)d`: A space if the appropriate level is not the current level, current character otherwise.

`Js.e?YqN-/<zk\(/<zhk\)dz`: Generate the string, save it to `J`.

`I-JdJ`: If `J` is not all spaces, print it out.

`Vz`: Loop `z` times.

Answer (score 7):

## GNU Bash + coreutils + indent, 135

```
eval paste "`tr '()' {}|indent -nut -i1 -nbap|sed 's/.*/<(fold -1<<<"&")/'|tr '
' \ `"|expand -t2|sed 'y/{}/()/;s/\(.\) /\1/g;s/ \+$//'
```

Input/output via STDIN/STDOUT:

```
$ ./telescopic.sh <<< "(()(()())()((())))(())"
(                )(  )
 ()(    )()(    )  ()
    ()()    (  )
             ()
$
```

`indent` does most of the heavy lifting, but needs to work with braces instead of parens.  The rest is [modification of this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/transpose-a-page-of-text/24501#24501) to transpose the output of `indent`.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 92

```python
def f(s,i=0,z=''):
 for x in s:b=x>'(';z+=[' ',x][i==b];i-=2*b-1
 if'('in z:print z;f(s,i-1)
```

Prints line by line. For a given line number `i` (actually, its negation), goes through the input string `s`, and makes a new string `z` that only contains the characters of `s` at depth `i`. This is done by incrementing or decrementing `i` to track the current depth, and adding the current characters when `i` is `0` adjusted for paren type, and otherwise adding a space.

Then, prints and recurses to the next `i` unless the current line was all spaces. Note that since the parens are balanced, the `i` after a loop is the same as at the start.

Python 3 would be same except for a character for `print(z)`.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <strike>232</strike> <strike>226</strike> <strike>224</strike> 222 bytes

Golfed version:

```java
int i,j,k,l,m,a[];void f(String s){a=new int[s.length()];j=a.length;for(k=0;k<j;){a[k]=s.charAt(k++)<41?i++:--i;m=m<i?i:m;}for(k=0;k<m;k++)for(l=0;l<j;)System.out.print(k==a[l++]?i++%2<1?'(':l==j?")\n":')':l==j?'\n':' ');}
```

Long version:

```java
int i, j, k, l, m, a[];
void f(String s) {
    a = new int[s.length()];
    j = a.length;
    for (k = 0; k < j;) {
        a[k] = s.charAt(k++) < 41 ? i++ : --i;
        m = m < i ? i : m;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
        for (l = 0; l < j;)
            System.out.print(k == a[l++] ? (i++ % 2 < 1 ? '(' : (l == j ? ")\n" : ')')) : (l == j ? '\n':' '));
}
```

The input string is analyzed first, looking for "(" and ")" to add/subtract a counter and store its value determining how far down the parentheses should go in an array while also keeping track of how deep the deepest one goes. Then the array is analyzed; the parentheses with lesser values are printed first, and will continue printing line by line until the maximum is reached.

I'll probably find ways to golf this further later.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript/ES6, 97 chars

```
f=s=>{for(n in s){m=o=d='';for(c of s)o+=n==(c<')'?d++:--d)?c:' ',m=m<d?d:m;n<m&&console.log(o)}}
```

### Usage

```
f("(()(()())()((())))(())")
```

### Explanation

```
fn=str=>{                          // accepts string of parenthesis
  for(line in str){                // repeat process n times where n = str.length
    max=output=depth='';           // max: max depth, output: what to print, depth: current depth
    for(char of str)               // iterate over chars of str
      output+=
        line==(char<')'?depth++:--depth)? // update depth, if line is equal to current depth
        char:' ',                  // append either '(', ')', or ' '
        max=max<depth?depth:max;   // update max depth
    line<max&&console.log(output)  // print if current line is less than max depth
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `n<m?console.log(o):0`, you can use `n<m&&console.log(o)` which saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 5):

## cheating :(  <s>Retina + TeX, N bytes</s> cheating :(

This only works if you render(?) the output using MathJax or some other TeX, which is currently disabled for this SE :(

```
\(
({
\)
})
\{\(
_{(
```

Each line should be in a different file, but you can test it by using `Retina -e "\(" -e "({" -e "\)" -e "})" -e "\{\(" -e "_{("` (or the equivalent sed command `sed -e "s/(/({/g;s/)/})/g;s/{(/_{(/g"`). Input is passed through STDIN.

This works by enclosing the contents of each pair of parentheses in braces, and then subscripting all the items inside them.

### Output

```
(((())))
(_{(_{(_{({})})})})

()(())((()))(())()
({})(_{({})})(_{(_{({})})})(_{({})})({})

((()())()(()(())()))
(_{(_{({})({})})({})(_{({})(_{({})})({})})})
```

[image: TeX Output]

Comment: I'm flattered that you've used Retina, and this is nice thinking-outside-the-box but that's not quite what the output is supposed to look like. ;) In particular this violates the alternative formulation "Another way to look at it is that the parentheses at depth n are moved to line n, while keeping their horizontal position." I'd be very impressed by a pure, rule-compliant Retina solution though and *might* hand out a bounty for it. ;)

Comment: `In total the lines must not be longer than twice the length of the input string`.
Changing line 2 to `(\,{` and line 4 to `}\,)` means that the output fits this (although the vertical depth is still wrong : ( )

Comment: Well, I managed to make rule-compliant solution : )

Comment: Nice job. I guess that means you can delete the cheaty answer now. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>43 41</s> 36 bytes

Not too golfed (I think), but here goes my first attempt:

```
l:L,{)L<)_')=@~zS*\+}%_$0=,f{Se]}zN*
```

**How it works**

I am using the very handy fact that `)` and `(` in CJam mean increment and decrement respectively. Thus, I simply evaluate the brackets to get the depth.

```
l:L,{)L<)_')=@~zS*\+}%_$0=,f{Se]}zN*
l:L,{                    }%                "Store input line in L and iterate over [0,L)";
     )L<                                   "substr(L, 0, iterator + 1)";
        )                                  "Slice off the last character to stack";
         _')=                              "Put 0 on stack if the sliced character is (,
                                            else 1 if sliced character is )";
             @~                            "bring forth the remaining
                                            brackets after slicing and evaluate them";
               zS*                         "Stack has negative depth number, take absolute
                                            value and get that many spaces";
                  \+                       "Prepend to the sliced character";
                      _$0=,                "Get the maximum depth of brackets";
                           f{Se]}          "Pad enough spaces after each string to match
                                            the length of each part";
                                 zN*       "Transpose and join with new lines";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3AL%2C%7B)L%3C)_')%3D%40~zS*%5C%2B%7D%25_%240%3D%2Cf%7BSe%5D%7DzN*&input=(()(()())()((())))(()))

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 85 chars

```
function r=p(s)i=j=0;for b=s k=b==40;k&&++j;t(j,++i)=9-k;k||--j;r=char(t+32);end;end
```

It's an optimization of the naïve approach, which is actually pretty natural for Matlab and Octave:

```
function r=p(s)
i=j=1;
for b=s
 if b=='(' t(++j,i++)='(' else t(j--,i++)=')' end; end; t(~t)=' '; r=char(t);
end;
```

The table `t`  may even not yet exist, and we may assign to any element right away, and it reshapes to the smallest dimension that is required for this element to exist which is quite convenient.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>91</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
$t=<>;{$_=$t;s/\((?{$l++})|.(?{--$l})/$^R==$c?$&:$"/ge;print,++$c,redo if/\S/}
```

- $t is the input string.
- $c is the depth we want to print on the current line.
- $l is the depth we are at after encountering a paren.
- $l is updated in [regex embedded code blocks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3F%7B-code-%7D)).
- $^R is the result of the most recent code block.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 154 bytes

```
f h('(':s)=h:f(h+1)s;f h(')':s)=(h-1):f(h-1)s;f _ _=[]
main=interact$ \s->unlines[[if i==h then c else ' '|(c,i)<-zip s l]|let l=f 0 s,h<-[0..maximum l]]
```

same idea as the other Haskell solution, but somewhat shorter. - Usage:

```
echo  '(((())())(()))' | runghc Golf.hs
```

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 13 bytes

```
y_ùZ<')?°T:T´
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=eV/5WjwnKT+wVDpUtA==&input=IigoKCkoKSkoKSgoKSgoKSkoKSkpIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
y_                :Transpose, pass each column Z through a function and transpose back
   Z<')           :  Is Z less than ")", i.e., is Z equal to "("?
       ?          :  If so
        °T        :   Prefix increment variable T (initially 0)
          :       :  Else
           T´     :   Postfix decrement T
  ù               :  Left pad Z with spaces to length T
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 338 bytes

```
([]){(({})[()]<([{}][])([][()]){({}[()]<(({}<(({})(())){({}[()]<([{}]())>)}>{})<({}{})((){[()](<{}<>((((()()()()){}){}){})<>>)}{}){{}(({})<>)(<>)}{}(({})(())){({}[()]<([{}])>)}{}>{}<({}<(([])<{{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>)<>>)<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>>)>)}{}{}<>((()()()()()){})<>>)}{}{{}}<>{{}{}(({})[((((()()()){}())){}{}){}]())}{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU85DgMhDPzLVp4iP7As5R2IYpMmUaQt0lq8nYwNaLcJl8wceHh89/fx2p@f3qVUuIg3FEFVKd4qIcJxJ@VtECzygAhwwcNAxNCMpBIfGg9alC6TGBgTZMdSoydKb/muGkQT@tcGyVoEyTDMqeGOHrTHvUVtGPt0T4UtPosZDddoU8NXSbqvMOX8AlWZLKPn10O/OvDsvW9THELurd/uPw)

### Idea

The idea for this program is that we make a number of passes over the string.  Each time we make a pass we keep track of a counter, we decrement the counter if we encounter a `(` and increment it if we encounter a `)`.  If `(` brings it to -1 we copy it to the offstack and if `)` brings it to zero we copy it to the offstack.  Otherwise we just copy a space.  We do this as many times as the length of the string starting the counter at 0 the first time and decreasing it each loop.  This way we catch the different layers in order.  When we are done we just trim characters until we reach a `)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2IDÇÉü+>4αΛ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyNPlcPvhzsN7tO1Mzm08N/v/fw0NDU0NTSDSACMQWxPK0gCzoZJgDpAFAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
2        # Push 2
I        # Push the input-string
D        # Create a copy of the input-string,
 Ç       # and convert it to a list of codepoint integers: ")"→41; "("→40
  É      # Check for each if it's odd: ")"→1; "("→0
   ü     # For each overlapping pair:
    +    #  Add them together: "(("→0; "()"→1; ")("→1; "))"→2
     >   # Increase each by 1: "(("→1; "()"→2; ")("→2; "))"→3
      4α # Take the absolute difference with 4: "(("→3; "()"→2; ")("→2; "))"→1
Λ        # Use the Canvas builtin with the given three arguments:
         #  - Directions: the list of 123 we created, for ↗→↘ respectively
         #  - What to draw: the third remaining copy of the input-string
         #  - Line-lengths per step: the 2
```

Here a step-by-step explanation of the output for input `(()(()())()((())))(())`:

Preparation step: the overlapping pairs are `["((","()",")(","((","()",")(","()","))",")(","()",")(","((","((","()","))","))","))",")(","((","()","))"]`, which are mapped with `DÇÉü+>4α` to `[3,2,2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,2,1]`, which indicate the directions `[↘,→,→,↘,→,→,→,↗,→,→,→,↘,↘,→,↗,↗,↗,→,↘,→,↗]`:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

When we use the Canvas builtin, it then draws like this:

Step 1: draw `2` characters (`((`) in direction `3` (`↘`):

```python
(
 (
```

Step 2: draw `2-1` characters (`)`) in direction `2` (`→`):

```python
(
 ()
```

Step 3: draw `2-1` characters (`(`) in direction `2` (`→`):

```python
(
 ()(
```

Step 4: draw `2-1` characters (`(`) in direction `3` (`↘`):

```python
(
 ()(
    (
```

Etc.

For an in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin I can refer to [this 05AB1E tip of mine.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
ZJ:sX{%Aa?DiUi-1}._Ma
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhZbo7ysiiOqVR0T7V0yQzN1DWv14n0TIXJQJbuilTQ0NEFIUxNEAylNEFcTbggA) Or, here's a 25-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/OKLaMVHVyF5XN1NbO1PXsFYv3jcxysWq@P///7o5/zU0NEFIUxNEAylNEFcTAA)

#### Reminiscence

Pip, old chap, how far we've come.

[This clunky 53-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49062/16766) was my first Pip answer on this site, over six years ago. I'd like to leave that answer untouched as a historical artifact, so I'm posting my modern Pip solution here separately. It's pretty clear that the two are different languages anyway. The old solution doesn't even work in modern Pip (though it still does on the TIO version).

#### Explanation

```lisp
ZJ:sX{%Aa?DiUi-1}._Ma
                      ; s is space; i is 0; a is command-line arg (implicit)
                   Ma ; Map this function to each character in the argument:
     { Aa       }     ;   The ASCII code of the character
      %               ;   Mod 2
         ?            ;   Is that truthy (1, close paren) or falsey (0, open paren)?
          Di          ;    If truthy, decrement i and return it
            Ui        ;    If falsey, increment i
              -1      ;    and return i-1 (i.e. the previous value of i)
   sX                 ;   Make a string of that many spaces
                 ._   ;   Concatenate the parenthesis to it
ZJ:                   ; Zip the list of strings to transpose it, padding to
                      ; a rectangle using spaces
                      ; Autoprint (implicit), each sublist on its own line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>119</s> <s>115</s> 114

```
->s{r=[""]*s.size
d=0
s.chars.map{|l|r.map!{|s|s+" "}
b=l>"("?1:0
d-=b
r[d][-1]=l
d+=1-b}.max.times{|i|puts r[i]}}
```

Explanation:

```
->s{r=[""]*s.size  # Take an array of strings big enough
d=0                # This will contain the current depth
s.chars.map{|l|r.map!{|s|s+" "}  # Add a new space to every array
b=l>"("?1:0       # Inc/Dec value of the depth
d-=b               # Decrement depth if we are at a closing paren
r[d][-1]=l         # Set the corresponding space to the actual open/close paren
d+=1-b             # Increment the depth if we are at a opening paren
}.max.times{|i|puts r[i]}}  # Print only the lines up to the max depth
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, 46

Not as great as the other 'golfing languages', but in my defence: J is terrible with strings.

```
[:|:(((,~(' '#~]))"0)(0,2%~[:+/\2+/\1-'(('i.]))~
```

Takes the string as input for a function. There's also probably a better way to do it in J.

### Usage:

```
   f=:[:|:(((,~(' '#~]))"0)(0,2%~[:+/\2+/\1-'(('i.]))~
   f '(()(()())()((())))(())'
(                )(  )
 ()(    )()(    )  () 
    ()()    (  )      
             ()
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49063/134) for another way of doing this in J.

Comment: Personally, I think that J is perfectly well-suited for strings. You just need to think with arrays.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>233</s> 214 bytes

```
void f(String s){int p,x,d,l=s.length();char c,m[]=new char[l*l];java.util.Arrays.fill(m,' ');p=x=0;while(x<l){d=(c=s.charAt(x))==40?p++:--p;m[d*l+x++]=c;}for(x=0;x<l*l;x++)System.out.print((x%l==0?"\n":"")+m[x]);}
```

Indented:

```
void f(String s){
    int p, x, d, l = s.length();
    char c, m[] = new char[l * l];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(m, ' ');
    p = x = 0;
    while (x < l){
        d = (c = s.charAt(x)) == 40
                ? p++
                : --p;
        m[d * l + x++] = c;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < l * l; x++)
        System.out.print((x % l == 0 ? "\n" : "") + m[x]);
}
```

I guess the final loop could be shortened, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader. ;-)

---

Old, 233 bytes answer:

```
void f(String s){int y=s.length(),x=0;char[][]m=new char[y][y];for(char[]q:m)java.util.Arrays.fill(q,' ');y=0;for(char c:s.toCharArray())if(c=='(')m[y++][x++]=c;else m[--y][x++]=c;for(char[]q:m)System.out.println(String.valueOf(q));}
```

Indented:

```
static void f(String s) {
    int y = s.length(), x = 0;
    char[][] m = new char[y][y];
    for(char[] q : m)
        java.util.Arrays.fill(q, ' ');
    y = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
        if(c == '(')
            m[y++][x++] = c;
        else
            m[--y][x++] = c;
    for(char[] q : m)
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(q));
}
```

Comment: I know it's been more than a year, but "I guess the final loop could be shortened, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader. ;-)"; you're indeed right. It can be changed from `for(x=0;x<l*l;x++)System.out.print((x%l==0?"\n":"")+m[x]);` to `for(x=0;x<l*l;)System.out.print((x%l==0?"\n":"")+m[x++]);` for -1 byte. Also, you can save 2 more bytes by removing `p=x=0` and just use `int p=0,x=0,` at initialization of the fields instead. In total it becomes **211 bytes**.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>118</strike> 117 Bytes

Another answer in C, but mine is shorter.

```
c;d;main(m,v)int**v;{while(d++<m){char*p=v[1];while(*p)c+=*p==40,putchar(c-d?*p:32),m=c>m?c:m,c-=*p++==41;puts("");}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
c; /* current depth */
d; /* depth to print in current row */
main(m,v)int**v;{
    while(d++<m) {
        char*p=v[1];
        while(*p){
            c+=*p==40;           /* 40 = '(' */
            putchar(c-d?*p:32); /* 32 = ' ' (space) */
            m=c>m?c:m;           /* search maximum depth */
            c-=*p++==41;         /* 41 = ')' */
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

And it works!

```
% ./telescope '()(())((()))(())()'
()(  )(    )(  )()
   ()  (  )  ()
        ()
% ./telescope '((()())()(()(())()))'
(                  )
 (    )()(        )
  ()()    ()(  )()
             ()
```

Comment: Quite an elegant solution, however `putchar(c-d?32:*p)` is one character shorter than `putchar(c==d?*p:32)` .

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, 424 bytes

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set s=%1
set a=1
:c
if defined s (set/ac+=1
set "z="
if "%s:~0,1%"=="(" (set "1=(")else (set/aa-=1
set "1=)")
for %%a in (!a!)do for /f usebackq %%b in (`powershell "'!l%%a!'".Length`)do (set/ay=!c!-%%b
for /l %%a in (1,1,!y!)do set z= !z!
set "l%%a=!l%%a!!z!!1!")
if "%s:~0,1%"=="(" set/aa+=1
if !a! GTR !l! set/al=!a!-1
set "s=%s:~1%"
goto c)
for /l %%a in (1,1,!l!)do echo !l%%a!
```

### Un-golfed:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set s=%1
set a=1
set c=0
set l=0

:c
if defined s (
    set /a c+=1
    set "z="
    if "%s:~0,1%"=="(" (
        set "1=("
    ) else (
        set /a a-=1
        set "1=)"
    )
    for %%a in (!a!) do for /f usebackq %%b in (`powershell "'!l%%a!'".Length`) do (
        set /a y=!c!-%%b
        for /l %%a in (1,1,!y!) do set z= !z!
        set "l%%a=!l%%a!!z!!1!"
    )
    if "%s:~0,1%"=="(" set /a a+=1
    if !a! GTR !l! set /a l=!a!-1
    set "s=%s:~1%"
    goto c
)

for /l %%a in (1,1,!l!) do echo !l%%a!
```

Example:

```
h:\>par.bat (((())())(()))
 (            )
  (      )(  )
   (  )()  ()
    ()
```

Comment: `-1` bytes: `usebackq` => `useback`

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 195 bytes

First try at golf - yell if I did something wrong.

Alternative C# version using SetCursorPosition and working left to right taking the input as a commandline arg.

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[] a){Action<int,int>p=Console.SetCursorPosition;int r=0,c=0;foreach(var x in a[0]){r+=x==')'?-1:0;p(c,r);Console.Write(x);r+=x=='('?1:0;p(c,r);c++;}}}
```

I thought it would be fun to adjust the write position based on the open/close paren and not full lines.  Close paren moves the position up before writing; open paren moves it down after writing.  Actioning SetCursorPosition saves five bytes.  Moving the cursor to the next line after the output would take quite a bit extra.

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        Action<int, int> p = Console.SetCursorPosition;
        int r = 0, c = 0;
        foreach (var x in a[0])
        {            
            r += x == ')' ? -1 : 0;
            p(c, r);
            Console.Write(x);
            r += x == '(' ? 1 : 0;
            p(c, r);
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, <s>356</s> 335 bytes

I know that there already exists a Batch solution for this challenge, but this one is golfed significantly more and seems to take a different approach. Most importantly, the other batch solution contains at least one powershell command; this solution does not.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set p=%1
set p=%p:(="(",%
set p=%p:)=")",%
set c=0
for %%a in (%p%)do (if ")"==%%a set/ac-=1
set d=!d!,!c!%%~a
if "("==%%a set/ac+=1&if !c! GTR !m! set m=!c!)
set/am-=1
for /l %%a in (0,1,!m!)do (for %%b in (!d!)do (set t=%%b
if "%%a"=="!t:~0,-1!" (cd|set/p=!t:~-1!)else (cd|set/p=. ))
echo.)
```

There is a  backspace character (`U+0008`) on the second to last line following the dot (line 12, column 57). This isn't visible in the code posted here but is included in the byte count.

Comment: Somebody else actually submitting an answer in Batch - Nice one +1.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 107 bytes

```hs
h#('(':s)=h:(h+1)#s
h#(_:s)|k<-h-1=k:k#s
_#_=[]
g s=[do(c,i)<-zip s$0#s;max" "[c|i==h]|h<-[0..maximum$0#s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoMwEIXhfU8xGMEJbUS31jlJCBKsmCEmLY1CKd49TeH9m4/nbPLLtuXsBDbYDEmSG9BdeynSpdhU5PSjcqonP/iCk5hIm8sKifTjifON5ai@/IJUdyLdg/1UUOn5ZCJnTjcq3bVtUQ5H@D@MycFyBAKO@/K28w41HHHjuCRoYc2IKMukLP0A)

Based on [d8d0d65b3f7cf42's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49191/56433).

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 227 bytes

```
n _ []=[]
n h ('(':r)=('(',h):n(h+1)r
n d (')':r)=let h=d-1 in(')',h):n h r
m n []=n
m n ((_,h):r)=m(max h n)r
p s=let v=n 0 s;h=m 0 v;in map(\d->map(\(b,l)->if l==d then b else ' ')v)[0..h]
main=fmap p getLine>>=mapM_ putStrLn
```

Comment: You can save a few spaces with operators: e.g. `n#[]` instead of `m n []`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 76 bytes

```
$a[/\(/?$l++:--$l][$i++]=$_ for split//,<>;print map{$_||' '}@$_,"\n"for@a
```

No `use strict` here :)

Answer (score 2):

## Lex, 94 bytes

Depends on Linux console codes. With gcc, you can cut out four bytes by replacing both instances of `\33` with an actual escape character.

```
%%
 int p[2]={0};
\( printf("(\33D");++p[!*p];
\) printf("\33M)");--*p;
\n while(p[1]--)ECHO;
```

To compile and run:

```
$ flex -o telescopic.c telescopic.l
$ gcc -o telecopic telescopic.c -lfl
$ ./telescopic
(()(()())()((())))(())
(                )(  )
 ()(    )()(    )  ()
    ()()    (  )
             ()
--- type ctrl-D ---
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 166 bytes

Not much to be said:

```py
m,c,l=list(input()),0,[]
for j in m:c+=1if j=='('else-1;l+=[c-1if j=='('else c]
for i in range(max(l)+1):
 t,p='',0
 for q in m:t+=q if l[p]==i else' ';p+=1
 print t
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
OḂ-*Ä+ƲṬ€z0ao⁶Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4Y4mXa3DLdrHNj3cueZR05oqg8T8R43bIv///6@koaEJQpqaIBpIaYK4mkoA)

Went through [quite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99fV8vQTvtwy7FND3euedS0psogMf9R47bI////K2loaIKQpiaIBlKaIK6mEgA) [a](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19X63CL9sMdTVz@h9sf7lzzqGlNlUFi/qPGbZH///9X0tDQBCFNTRANpDRBXE0lAA) [few](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99fV@twi7b/wx1NKg93rnnUtKbKIDH/UeO2yP///ytpaGiCkKYmiAZSmiCuphIA) 16-byters before arriving at this...

```
O                  Codepoints
 Ḃ                 mod 2. ('(' -> 0, ')' -> 1)
    Ä              Cumulative sums of
  -*               -1 to the power of each,
     +Ʋ            plus the corresponding original residues.
       Ṭ€          For each, an array with 1 at that index and 0 elsewhere.
         z0        Zip filling with zeroes,
           a       replace ones with corresponding elements of the input string,
            o⁶     replace zeroes with spaces,
              Y    join on newlines.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 29 bytes

```
{+(|/i)$(-i:m-+\m-~m:2!x)$'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6rW1qjRz9RU0dDNtMrV1Y7J1a3LtTJSrNBUUa+o5eLiSlNQ0tBU4kpQMLBSUFKC8IFAEwjQRDVBohApMAtTlyZYWAOqEtkEAIy4GVY=)

- `(...)$'x` left-pad each character of the input by the corresponding number of spaces

  - `m:2!x` take the input string mod 2 and store in `m`; translates `"("` into `0` and `")"` into `1`
  - `m-~m` convert `0`s to `-1`s (leaving `1`s as-is)
  - `i:m-+\` calculate the "depth" of each character, storing in `i`
  - `-i` negate to left-pad (positive numbers will right-pad)
- `+(|/i)$` right-pad each string with spaces to the same length, then transpose the result

Answer (score 1):

## IDL 8.4, <s>173</s> 177 bytes

This is similar enough to the formatter challenge that I had half a solution already. IDL is still a terrible golfing language, but I'm pretty happy with how this worked out.

```
read,(p='')&a=[0:strlen(p)-1]&c=strmid(p,a,1)&e=c.map(lambda(x,d:'('eq x:d++:d---1)))&print,[0:max(e)].map(lambda(x,y,z:y.reduce(lambda(t,u,v,w,:t+(w eq v?u:' ')),x,z),c,a))&end
```

Un-golfed:

```
read,(p='') ;read a string from input
a=[0:strlen(p)-1] ;index array to the input
c=strmid(p,a,1) ;split the input into an array of 1-char substrings
e=c.map(lambda(x,d:'('eq x:d++:d---1))) ;for each substring, increment depth if ( and decrement otherwise, saving depth each time
print,[0:max(e)].map(lambda(x,y,z:y.reduce(lambda(t,u,v,w,:t+(w eq v?u:' ')),x,z),c,a)) ;print an array of strings, each one including the parens in that depth level.
end ;end the script
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 196 bytes

Very simple complete program that takes input via STDIN, and outputs to STDOUT. I should like to get rid of the `S.Length`, but haven't found a way that pays.

```c#
using Q=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var S=Q.ReadLine();for(int i=0,c;++i<S.Length;){var r="";c=0;foreach(var k in S)r+=(c+=81-k*2)+k-40==i?k:' ';if(r.Contains("("))Q.WriteLine(r);}}}
```

It simply iterates over the input a number of times (input length - 1), keeping track of the parentheses "depth", and comparing it to the current iteration count (`i`) - if they match, then it adds the current parenthesis to a string, to be printed at the end of the iteration. Because more iterations may be done than necessary, it only prints the iteration result (`r`) if it contains a parenthesis.

```c#
using Q=System.Console;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var S=Q.ReadLine(); // read input

        for(int i=0,c;
            ++i<S.Length; // can't be more than S.Length - 1 lines of output
            )
        {
            var r=""; // reset result
            c=0; // current paren depth
            foreach(var k in S) // for each char in input
                r+= // append something...
                    (c+=81-k*2) // move c
                    +k-40==i? // check if we should output the current char
                        k:
                        ' '; // otherwise a space
            if(r.Contains("(")) // only print if there is some content
                Q.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Uses [current version (4.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases) of the [language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), which is *newer* than this challenge (but the challenge was so attractive...)

```
j32-t8=2*1-TTo3X53$X+ZSYsP0hP1+wtn:wZ?32+c
```

*EDIT (May 20, 2016): [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ajMyLXQ4PTIqMS1UVG8zWDUzJFkrWlNZc1AwaFAxK3d0bjp3Wj8zMitj&input=KCkoKCkpKCgoKSkpKCgpKSgp) with `X+` replaced by `Y+`, according to version 18.0.0 of the language.*

#### Example

```
>> matl j32-t8=2*1-TTo3X53$X+ZSYs0wh1+wtn:wZ?32+c
> ()(())((()))(())()
()(  )(    )(  )()
   ()  (  )  ()   
        ()
```

#### Explanation

The general idea is to use [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) to analyze pairs of consecutive symbols. There are four possible pairs:

- `((`: the second symbol should be on a lower line than the first
- `))`: the second symbol should be on a higher line than the first
- `()` or `)(`: the second symbol should be on the same line as the first

When analyzing each pair, the line of the first symbol is already known, and the analysis tells the line of the second. Then the nex pair is analyzed, obtained by advancing one symbol, that is, with overlapping.

```
j           % input string                                     
32          % ASCII code of space character
-           % subtraction. Will give 8 or 9 for '(' and ')'
t8=         % 1 for '(' symbols, 0 for ')'
2*1-        % convert into 1 / -1
TTo         % array [1 1] (for convolution)
3X5         % 'valid' flag for convolution
3$          % specify three inputs for convolution
X+          % convolution                                      
ZS          % sign function            
Ys          % cumulative sum                                   
0wh         % prepend a 0
1+          % add 1. This gives line number of each symbol
wtn:w       % Vector [1 2 ... n] where n is string length. Rearrange
Z?          % create (sparse) matrix with three inputs: row, col, val
32+c        % add space code and convert to chat
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x].map((_,n,s)=>s.map(c=>(c=='('?n--:++n)?' ':c).join``).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYdBCoNADEX3PUV3SdDJASwZd16iFGeYSlFsIk4p3n60Unif998UvzGndVw@Tu05lE7KJv7OzNuD33FB7GutM4nPZybxxwQQWnWuqSqlFq7QJOLJRg3h70sot2SabR54thd2CIhISAd48vsERGUH)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 85 bytes, just enough lines

```javascript
x=>[...x].map((_,n,s)=>(Q=s.map(c=>(c=='('?n--:++n)?' ':c).join``)<1?'':Q+`
`).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcixCsIwEIDh3adwuzvSHrhGr9m6dxYxIRZpqZfSiPTtYy0I//Dxj@ETclyG@V1revSllbJKc2Xm9cavMCPeK60ySYOd5P3EzVEEEJzWtTVGycERbCQe06De0@XkAGxn/MH/XznHpDlNPU/piS0CIhLSFu79TEBUvg)

Comment: Invalid, "You may optionally print a single trailing newline."

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＦＳ¿⁼(ι↘(«Ｍ↑)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU27DoMwDJzJV1hMtgQ/QNd26FCpatUPQIhHJEQoBDpU/fY0dgLiFp/vzueqK6fKlL1zjZkAr8O42Ked9NAikUp0A3h5L2U/Y4ppBprF5O59i8XZfIaHbjubgTfppJK6n2v4@sTNrDUWr5HFGE9JIj/nkFy@9i7XDj3Iw0tMwiaM2CNhGE3O5YavEQSkQBiBAmYETAD9BG70SvCF0eaFpKQURMgm2MqP2B8h7W54SuEwPqND47H2Dw)

#### Explanation

```
ＦＳ             For each character in next input as string
    ¿⁼(ι         If character is "("
        ↘(       Print "(" down and to the right - this is equivalent to printing "(" and moving down
          «Ｍ↑)  Else move up and print ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>117</s> 114 bytes

```hs
f(y:b)|a<-sum[1|y=='(']=a:map(+(2*a-1))(f b)
f[]=[]
p s=[[last$' ':[a|b==i]|(b,a)<-zip(f s)s]|i<-[1..maximum$f s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEEX3PcUghcyoKdRl6ZzCZchiAi0GmxJMA1Zy91iFv3g8HvyHpOe0LLXOuA@Oiow65WD6sjMrVJZlCBLxgrez6J4IZ3DUzMaysU2ExMYskrZWgRqMFMfsbUF3FRr1x8cjT5Rs8aM2fdcFefuQQ3tYa2sQvwIDxrzdt1eX18WvUyJoIcIJEQmPP8L/fkyn@gU)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>94</s> <s>99</s> <s>97</s> 96

```
i,j,k,l;f(char*s){for(l=0;!i--;l-=puts(""))for(j=0;k=s[j++];putchar((k&1?--l:l++)?32:k))i&=l<2;}
```

Pure C version that doesn't use the consoles escape codes. Ungolfed:

```
i,j,k,l;                 // stop,iterator,current char,level
f(char*s){
  for(l=0;               // reset level
      !i--;              // stop ? return : stop = 1;
      l-=puts(""))      // new line + next level
    for(j=0;
        k=s[j++];        // for each char
        putchar(
          (k&1?--l:l++)  // char == 41 ? prev level : next level
          ?32:k))        // only print brackets at level 0
      i&=l<2;            // if level > 1 then don't stop
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BDoIwEETvfkXlQHaFJoKeqIQPEQ@kES2tSCieCN@OLcWD6IE9befNbIfTG@fjKMIqlKFiJfB70e409uWzBZXu2VZQyhRNm1enwfMQLagMkKk@V0FwYYbYEID0o4xSlaggwOwQJxJR@Kk6xWwYRd2RRyFqwH5DSNOadwkeL/SVRElu5LzOaw@ZgUYHdOvH59AyGNugGTTzHZ/FNUcO0@/W70LTtmyzxGsOH107nAIw3/jT9Mdg4TC@AQ)

Changelog:

- *+5 Byte* Temporary fix to match rules
- *-2 Byte* Switch `!i++` to `!i--` drops the need to reset `i`
- *-1 Byte* Switch `puts(""),--l` to `l-=puts("")` Thanks to @ceilingcat

Comment: I'm unable to find the relevant meta-post, but I'm pretty sure functions should be self-contained when run multiple times. So I think you should add `i=j=k=l=0` to your code instead of resetting them in your main-method. I'll see if I can find the meta-post to explain it more clearly though, but I've had other people make these kind of comments on my answers in the past.. Nice answer nonetheless, so +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [Here it is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/76162) Edit: mwahahaha

Comment: [Found the meta-post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable/), and [here another relevant one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/what-are-our-rules-about-additional-code-accompanying-function-submissions/). EDIT: @JoKing You beat me to it by 10 sec. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen A damn you're right what a sad day. Temp fix it at the cost of 5 byte. Hopefully I can get rid of some of them again. Ideas ? ;)

Comment: @Christoph Unfortunately I don't see anything to golf (although there might of course be). I'm not too skilled in C to be completely honest. It seems already pretty well-golfed to me, hence the upvote I gave. ;)

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one! Its only guaranteed to return a non negative number but it seems to return 1 in this case on tio :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## VIM, 101 bytes

`↵` = Enter

```
qwlmto<esc>`t@wq@w:s/()/(*)/g↵:set ve=all↵:set nows:↵set nosol↵qqvi)ygvr jPk/(↵@qq@qjjdGqeGl?*↵<C-V>ggoGr|@eq@e:%s/|//↵
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 65 bytes

```
./\S/{*\`\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
($.1* )
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
 $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PPyZYv1orJiFGQ0PD3kbXyE4jRkNTK0ZTU0szRpNLQ0XPUEtBkwu7rIKKocL//xpAZUCgCQRcGpogBoQHZoHlNMEsDagkUAoA) Note: Trailing space. Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
```

Don't print the spaces left over at the end.

```
/\S/{
```

Repeat until there are only spaces left.

```
*\`
```

Print the result of this substitution without changing the current value.

```
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
($.1* )
```

Match pairs of balanced parentheses and replace their content with a run of spaces of the same length.

```
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
 $1
```

Match balanced parentheses and replace the outer pairs with spaces.

For [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) you have the choice of this 60 byte code:

```
{*`\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
($.1$* )
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)
 $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wv1orIUZDQ8PeRtfITiNGQ1MrRlNTSzNGk0tDRc9QRUtBkwu7tIKKocL//xpAdUCgCQRcGpogBoQHZoHlNMEsDagkUAoA) Note: Trailing space. Link includes test cases. Explanation: The differences are as follows:

- Retina 0.8.2 doesn't have a while loop, only a convergence loop. However, this ends up printing blank lines while waiting for the loop to converge.
- Retina 0.8.2 uses `*` for much the same effect as `.*\`.
- Retina 0.8.2 uses `$*` instead of `*` in the replacement.

Alternatively, if the blank lines are a problem, you can use this 92 byte code:

```
{`.+$
$&¶$&
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)(?=.*¶.*$)
($.1$* )
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)(?=.*$)
 $1 
¶ +$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxDsIwEAT7e4WLw9o9FEumBlLyCRehSJEmBaLjX36AP2YOQ81Wc5rde6zPbb/3A25Lfy3pqKKxVY1SAMzn6XRFAa2QxkLMl2StJlMKNGW1wD9NbwXNQVoN/rh3@MpDj4Af@F6DhuMg/KSrNw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
{`
```

Repeat until the value converges.

```
.+$
$&¶$&
```

Duplicate the last line.

```
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)(?=.*¶.*$)
($.1$* )
```

Match pairs of balanced parentheses on what used to be the last line and replace their content with a run of spaces of the same length.

```
\(((?<-2>(\()*\))*)\)(?=.*$)
 $1
```

Match pairs of balanced parentheses on the last line and replace the outer pairs with spaces.

```
¶ +$
```

Delete the last line if it's only spaces. This allows the loop to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 96 bytes

```hs
f s=fst$span(any(>' '))[do
c:d<-scanr(:)[]s
max" "[c|sum[1|')'<-d]-sum[1|'('<-c:d]==i]|i<-[0..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEEX3PcUQCsksUnRbGk@gK5chiyGxWGxi6LSg0LvHFIQPj7d4/0n8esxzKSOwGXltOVNSlL7qIkEi2vBufB8GzZ7Sonq0jptIHwHC@p23aM@7RDno4PTfVLWaOGMmt0@Dtqeuc65EmhIYqH8AkfIN8rbe1@WaoIURhFJ4DPFgBR6KovwA)

Comment: How does this work? I can’t really read Haskell but this looks cool

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-Rx`, 17 bytes

```
¬£®¥'(?Y´:°Y ?S:Z
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=rKOupScoP1m0OrBZID9TOlo=&input=LVJ4CiIoKSgoKSkoKCgpKSkoKCkpKCki)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Uq mXYZ{UmZ{Z=='(?Y--:++Y ?S:Z

Uq      Convert the input string into array of chars
mXYZ{   Map with the function...
          Here, Y (index) is used as the desired level of "telescoping"
UmZ{      Map on the original input string with the function...
Z=='(?      If this char is "("...
Y--:          Decrement Y
++Y           Otherwise, increment Y
?           If Y is nonzero (i.e. this char is *not* at desired level)...
S:            Replace with a space
Z             Otherwise, use the char as-is

Flags:
-R      Join the resulting array with newline
-x      Trim the resulting string on both ends
```

Ported from [@l4m2's JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163417/78410). It actually fits into Japt's built-ins quite nicely, and trailing whitespaces can be conveniently removed with the use of `-x` flag.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 27 bytes

```
ƛC∷&-¥n꘍nC₂&+;:vLG£ƛ¥↲;ÞTv∑
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9BC%E2%88%B7%26-%C2%A5n%EA%98%8DnC%E2%82%82%26%2B%3B%3AvLG%C2%A3%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%86%B2%3B%C3%9ETv%E2%88%91&inputs=%27%28%28%29%28%28%29%28%29%29%28%29%28%28%28%29%29%29%29%28%28%29%29%27&header=&footer=)

A mess that I'm proud of. Thanks to lyxal for fixing a bug.

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 5.9, 149 bytes

```swift
var c=0,d=[0],t={i in(i+"",d=i.map{$0<")" ?(c,c+=1).0:(c-=1,c).1},{(0...d.max()!).map{e in.init(zip(i,d).map{$0.1==e ?$0.0:" "})}.joined}()("\n")).2}
```

I love it when I can shove everything into a single line of code (i.e. without using semicolons; I prefer to use newlines instead since they don't incur a byte penalty in Swift). `map(_:)` FTW! (Although, to be fair, tuple shenanigans make this relatively easy too...)

Here's the original, with an explanation ([and a JDoodle link](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Ysd)):

```swift
func telescope(_ input: String) -> String {
    // As an example, we'll pretend that `input` is
    // this string: "((()())()(()(())()))"
    
    // MARK: - Depth Calculation

    var currentDepth = 0
    let depths = input.map { character in
        switch character {
        // This is essentially equivalent to `currentDepth++`,
        // if that operator still existed in Swift (remember,
        // that one returns the value *before* incrementing).
        case "(": (currentDepth, currentDepth += 1).0
        
        // Likewise, this would be the same as `--currentDepth`
        // (the one that returns the value *after* decrementing).
        case ")": (currentDepth -= 1, currentDepth).1
        
        // If it isn't a parenthesis, we have some invalid input.
        default: fatalError("wtf?!?! that ain't a valid string!")
        }
    }
    
    // Now, for our example, `depths` is:
    // [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
    // (note that a depth of 0 is the topmost/outermost level)
    
    // Here's an alternative representation:
    // ((()())()(()(())()))
    // 01222211112223322210
    
    // MARK: - Tier Generation
    
    let depthRange = 0...depths.max()!
    let tiers = depthRange.map { depth in
        let inputWithDepths = zip(input, depths)
        let charactersOnThisTier = inputWithDepths.map { (character, otherDepth) in
            // If this character is on this tier, show it; otherwise, add a space.
            otherDepth == depth ? character : " "
        }
        return charactersOnThisTier
    }
    
    // MARK: - Joining
    
    let joinedTiers = tiers.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "\n")
    return joinedTiers
}
```