# Esolang-Comment-Template-Generator

Tags: code-golf, string, comment

Lots of people on this site use [esoteric languages](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page), and since these languages are unusual and hard to understand, they will frequently write an explanation in a certain format. For example, if the code was

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

And this languages uses `#` for comments, they would write an explanation like this:

```
a                #Explanation of what 'a' does
 bc              #Bc
   d             #d
    e            #Explanation of e
     fgh         #foobar
        ij       #hello world
          k      #etc.
           l     #so on
            mn   #and
              op #so forth
```

I frequently do this too, but every time I do this, I feel like creating the layout of text is really obnoxious and time-consuming. So I want you to create a "Esolang-Comment-Template-Generator" for me. For example, if we ignore the comments, the previous code has this template:

```
a                #
 bc              #
   d             #
    e            #
     fgh         #
        ij       #
          k      #
           l     #
            mn   #
              op #
```

## The Challenge:

You must write a program or function that takes two strings as input, and outputs this "Esolang-Comment-Template". The first input will be the code, but with bars (`|`) inserted where the newlines go. The second input is what we will use for comments. So our last example would have this for input:

```
"a|bc|d|e|fgh|ij|k|l|mn|op", "#"
```

Unfortunately this excludes bars from being part of the code input, but that's OK. You can assume that the comment input will be a single character. For simplicity's sake, the comment char will not be a bar. The code input will only contain printable ASCII, and it will not contain any newlines.

Hopefully you can infer what to do from the testcases, but I'll try to clarify some things.

You must split the code input up into "code-sections" on every bar. Then, each section of code is output on its own line and left-padded with the length of all the previous code (not including the bars). Then, each line is right-padded with enough spaces so that the last two characters on every line are "One additional space" + "The comment character".

One trailing newline is allowed.

Here is another example. For the input

```
"Hello|World", "/"
```

The first *section* of code is "Hello" and the second is "World". So it should give the output:

```
Hello      /
     World /
```

Here are some more samples:

```
Input:
"a|b|c|d|e|f|g", ","

Output:
a       ,
 b      ,
  c     ,
   d    ,
    e   ,
     f  ,
      g ,

Input:
"abcdefg", ":"

Output:
abcdefg :

Input:
"4|8|15|16|23|42", "%"

Output:
4          %
 8         %
  15       %
    16     %
      23   %
        42 %

Input:
"E|ac|h s|ecti|on is| one c|haracte|r longer| than the| last!", "!"

Output:
E                                                   !
 ac                                                 !
   h s                                              !
      ecti                                          !
          on is                                     !
                one c                               !
                     haracte                        !
                            r longer                !
                                     than the       !
                                              last! !

Input:
"This|Code|has||empty||sections", "@"

Output:
This                     @
    Code                 @
        has              @
                         @
           empty         @
                         @
                sections @
```

## Rules:

You may take these inputs and outputs in any reasonable format. For example, reading/writing a file, STDIN/STOUT, function arguments/return value, etc. As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to make your code as short as possible and you win if you can get the shortest solution in your language! I will also select the shortest solution as the overall winner. [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are banned.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49016/31625)

Comment: Are trailing blanks allowed?

Comment: Next step : a 3D representation for 2D languages

Comment: A bonus if you manage to do it without using the `|` character would be nice, so you can explain yourself

Comment: Can the comment character be a bar (`|`) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>28</s> <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

<s>Might be able to golf a little off.</s> A lot off, apparently!

```
jt+R+;zC.t.u+*lNdYcQ\|k
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jt%2BR%2B%3BzC.t.u%2B%2alNdYcQ%5C%7Ck&input=%22a%7Cbc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cfgh%7Cij%7Ck%7Cl%7Cmn%7Cop%22%0A%23&debug=0).

Answer (score 10):

## Java 11, <s>189</s> <s>159</s> 136 bytes

```java
s->c->{int p=0;for(var a:s.split("\\|"))System.out.println(" ".repeat(p)+a+" ".repeat(s.replace("|","").length()-(p+=a.length())+1)+c);}
```

-30 bytes converting Java 7 to Java 10 and optimizing the loops.
-23 bytes converting Java 10 to Java 11, so `String#repeat` builtin can be used.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVLBbhshEL37KyZbVQHtmtZJWlVxbFWyWuXSUyr1kPQwZtldHBYQYEtWxt/uYnvVxlUuCHhv3vDmscINjlf1814ajBF@oLYvI4CYMGkJq4yKddJGNGsrk3ZWfB82dw8paNtWb3EWzsZ1r8LdosOAMqkwn0MDs30cz@V4/qJtAj/7OG1cYBsMgLdRRG90YsXTExWcP2xjUr1w6yR87pKMZQUUIiivMDHPSyxfneNhY1AqVlBRFQUXRtk2dYyPmS9n@PfIywkvJZ/u9tNRNunXS5NNDl43TtfQZ//s5OzxNyA/zAIgqZifhrSUVJOipu1Ir@iZDPWWnC@qy3eXfPqKeq@McfTLBVNn8MM5mHVoEKI2w9V/8FLWqjkAt@fADX2hySeafKara7q5yoT354RvhJI6iKRyDOQs6EjgrIJ8e8qBAhhnWxUIUoc2L4ogB58ustrFudrPLpcvXK1ycSRSvU9boqiOEcfM/3ri70b//stxhsfy0wwhVjK3BjkMEhqB3psti1yglMonJoem8Ebmg/5u/wc)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->c->{                     // Method with String & char parameters and no return-type
  int p=0;                  //  Position-integer, starting at 0
  for(var a:s.split("\\|")) //  Loop over the parts split by "|":
    System.out.println(     //   Print with trailing newline:
      " ".repeat(p)         //    `p` amount of spaces
      +a                    //    plus the current part
      " ".repeat(s.replace("|","").length()-(p+=a.length())+1)
                            //    plus the correct trailing amount of spaces
                            //    (and add the length of the current part to `p` at the
                            //    same time)
      +c);}                 //    plus the current comment character
```

Answer (score 9):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\|
·$'¶$`±
T0-2`·±|p`___ `.+±.|·.+
```

The two input strings are separated by a space (which is unambiguous since we know that the comment delimiter is always a single character).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XHwKwrckJ8K2JGDCsQpUMC0yYMK3wrF8cGBfX18gYC4rwrEufMK3Lis&input=RXxhY3xoIHN8ZWN0aXxvbiBpc3wgb25lIGN8aGFyYWN0ZXxyIGxvbmdlcnwgdGhhbiB0aGV8IGxhc3QhICE)

Comment: Why do you need a space to delimit the strings? Since it is a single character, it could just be the last one.

Comment: @Adám I'm reusing it as the space separator in the final output.

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
\|cDslF2l-hd*Q+Zi:il?+ZK
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%7CcDslF2l-hd%2aQ%2BZi%3Ail%3F%2BZK&input=%23%0Aa%7Cbc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cfgh%7Cij%7Ck%7Cl%7Cmn%7Cop)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```js
f=
(s,c)=>s.split`|`.map((_,i,a)=>a.map((e,j)=>i-j?e.replace(/./g,` `):e).join``+` `+c).join`
`
;
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(s.value,c.value)><input id=s placeholder=Code><input id=c size=1 maxlength=1 value=#><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>107</s> <s>105</s> <s>102</s> 99 bytes

Tested with all test cases above

**EDIT** Golfed off 2 bytes by changing d=a.split("|");i=0 to d,i=a.split("|"),0
Not sure how I missed that one. Thanks @Oliver Ni

Another 3 bytes gone. Thanks again.

Suggestion from @Jonathan actually saves 3 bytes and takes it down to the magic 99. Thanks.

```
def c(a,b):
 d,i=a.split("|"),0
 for e in d:j=i+len(e);print" "*i+e+" "*(len("".join(d))-j+1)+b;i=j
```

Comment: Golfed it down 6 bytes

Comment: Golfed it down another byte

Comment: Hey @OliverNi , providing tips for golfing stuff down is appreciated, but editing code isn't really appropriate on this site ([source](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1619/31716)), so I've rolled back your edit. Feel free to post those tips as a comment though! I'm sure the OP would appreciate it, but it should be up to them to test it and choose if they want to use it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Firstly to @Oliver for taking the interest and the time to improve my humble effort and secondly to DJMcMayhem for clarifying what I believed to be the case but had not had a chance to comment on. Oliver - thanks again and please feel free to post changes as comments so that I can learn from your golfing experience.

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis around `" "*i` to ave 2 bytes

Comment: Also, change `len("".join(d))-(i+len(e)-1)` to `len("".join(d))-i-len(e)+1` to save another two bytes

Comment: You can also set a variable to `len(e)` like `for e in d:z=len(e)....` to save a byte because it is used twice

Comment: Tips 1 and 3 worked but 2 seemed to mess up the formatting of the comment characters (not in a vertical line). Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Hmm... I tworks for me

Comment: It's just the distributive property

Comment: Take it down to a nice round 100 with this as your for loop: `for e in d:j=i+len(e);print" "*i+e+" "*(len("".join(d))-j+1)+b;i=j`

Answer (score 4):

## GNU sed (85 + 1 for -r) 86

```
:s;h;:;s,\|( *)[^ \|](.),|\1 \2,;t;s,\|,,g
p;g;:l;s,^( *)[^ \|],\1 ,;tl;s,\|,,;/\S/bs
```

The inputs are strings separated by a space.

**Tests:**
input.txt:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g ,
abcdefg :
4|8|15|16|23|42 %
E|ac|h s|ecti|on is| one c|haracte|r longer| than the| last! !
This|Code|has||empty||sections @
```

Output:

```
$ cat input.txt | sed -rf template
a       ,
 b      ,
  c     ,
   d    ,
    e   ,
     f  ,
      g ,

abcdefg :

4          %
 8         %
  15       %
    16     %
      23   %
        42 %

E                                                   !
 ac                                                 !
   h s                                              !
      ecti                                          !
          on is                                     !
                one c                               !
                     haracte                        !
                            r longer                !
                                     than the       !
                                              last! !

This                     @
    Code                 @
        has              @
                         @
           empty         @
                         @
                sections @
```

Comment: The nameless label `:` is a GNU sed feature/bug and `\S` is I think an extension, so maybe the title should be `GNU sed`. Other than that, great code.

Comment: @seshoumara Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>125 124</s> 132 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @TuukkaX (missed golfing the space from `i, v`)

```python
def g(s,c):x=s.split('|');print((' '+c+'\n').join(' '*len(''.join(x[:i]))+v+' '*len(''.join(x[i+1:]))for i,v in enumerate(x))+' '+c)
```

All test cases on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/MWZ0Lx)

Comment: Your supposed to use `c` as the comment char, not `#`.

Comment: @OliverNi - uh that was a hit for the code in its current form.

Comment: @Makonede Looks like nobody got the reference

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>139</s> 135 bytes

```
s#p=j$foldl g("",0)s where g(a,n)c|c=='|'=(j(a,n)++"\n"++q n,n)|1>0=(a++[c],n+1);q m=' '<$[1..m];j(a,n)=a++q(sum[1|c<-s,c/='|']-n+1)++p
```

Saved 4 bytes by inlining a definition.

**Ungolfed:**

```
template :: String -> String -> String
template code comment = format $ foldl g ("", 0) code
    where g (acc, n) c
            | c == '|' = (format (acc, n) ++ "\n" ++ spaces n, n)
            | otherwise = (acc ++ [c], n+1)
          l = length $ filter (/= '|') code
          spaces n = replicate n ' '
          format (acc, n) = acc ++ spaces (l-n+1) ++ comment
```

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, <s>120</s> <s>113</s> 111 Bytes

```
def m(s,c){s.split(/\|/).inject(0,{e,t->println((' '*e+t).padRight(s.replace('|','').size()+1)+c);e+t.size()})}
```

**ungolfed***

```
def m(s,c){
  s.split(/\|/).inject(0, { e, t ->
    println((' '*e+t).padRight(s.replace('|','').size())+' '+c)
    e+t.size()
  })
}
```

## (First Draft with 120 Bytes)

```
def m(s,c){def l=0;s.split(/\|/).collect{l+=it.size();it.padLeft(l).padRight(s.replace('|','').size())+' '+c}.join('\n')}
```

**ungolfed***

```
def m(s,c){
  def l=0 // minimized version needs a semicolon here
  s.split(/\|/).collect{
    l+=it.size() // minimized version needs a semicolon here
    it.padLeft(l).padRight(s.replace('|','').size())+' '+c
  }.join('\n')
}
```

**Tests**

```
%> m('a|bc|d|e|fgh|ij|k|l|mn|op', '#')
a                #
 bc              #
   d             #
    e            #
     fgh         #
        ij       #
          k      #
           l     #
            mn   #
              op #

%> m('Hello|World', '/')
Hello      /
     World /

%> m('a|b|c|d|e|f|g', ',')
a       ,
 b      ,
  c     ,
   d    ,
    e   ,
     f  ,
      g ,

%> m('abcdefg', ':')
abcdefg :

%> m('4|8|15|16|23|42', '%')
4          %
 8         %
  15       %
    16     %
      23   %
        42 %

%> m('E|ac|h s|ecti|on is| one c|haracte|r longer| than the| last!', '!')
E                                                   !
 ac                                                 !
   h s                                              !
      ecti                                          !
          on is                                     !
                one c                               !
                     haracte                        !
                            r longer                !
                                     than the       !
                                              last! !

%> m('This|Code|has||empty||sections', '@')
This                     @
    Code                 @
        has              @
                         @
           empty         @
                         @
                sections @
```

Comment: How about `.padRight(s.replace('|','').size()+1)+c)`

Comment: good idea! thank you! saved another 2 chars!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>29</s> <s>38</s> <s>31</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'|„ǝʒ:'ǝ¡'ʒмεD®>úsg®+©s}.Bεð²J,
```

Can definitely be golfed, but at least its working now..
+9 bytes because `¡` (split) removes empty items automatically, so I had to add `'|„ǝʒ:'ǝ¡'ʒм`..
-2 bytes thanks to *@MagicOctopusUrn* by changing `'|„ǝʒ:'ǝ¡'ʒм` to `'|¶:.BεðÜ}` (current solution doesn't work on items with trailing spaces, but I've assumed that's allowed according to the test cases).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf8wNWFiMWX//yd84oCex53Kkjonx53CoSfKktC8zrVEwq4@w7pzZ8KuK8Kpc30uQs61w7DCskos//9hYmN8ZHxlfHxmZwoh)

**Explanation:**

```
'|¶:           # Take the first input, and replace every "|" with "¶"
               #  i.e. "abc|d|e||fg" → "abc¶d¶e¶¶fg" (¶ are new-lines in 05AB1E)
    .B         # Box all the items (appending trailing whitespace to make it a rectangle)
               #  i.e. "abc¶d¶e¶¶fg" → ['abc','d  ','e  ','   ','fg ']
      εðÜ}     # Remove all trailing spaces from each item
               #  i.e. ['abc','d  ','e  ','   ','fg '] → ['abc','d,'e','','fg']
               #  NOTE: `'|¡` would have resulted in ['abc','d','e','fd'], hence the use of
               #        Box which implicitly splits on new-lines to keep empty items
ε              # For-each:
 D             #  Duplicate the current item
  ®>ú          #  Prepend global_variable + 1 amount of spaces
               #  (+1 because the global_variable is -1 by default)
               #   i.e. "e" and 3+1 → "    e"
 sg            #  Swap so the duplicated item is at the top, and take its length
   ®+          #  Sum it with the global_variable
               #   i.e. "e" (→ 1) and 4 → 5
     ©         #  And store it as new global_variable
      s        #  Then swap so the space appended item is at the end again
       }       # And end the for-each loop
.B             # Box all the items (appending the appropriate amount of spaces)
               #  i.e. ['abc','   d','    e','     ','     fg']
               #   → ['abc    ','   d   ','    e  ','       ','     fg']
ε              # For-each again:
 ð             #  A space character
  I            #  The second input-character
   J           #  Join both together with the current item
    ,          #  And print the current row with trailing new-line
```

Comment: This is invalid if the code were to contain `ǝʒ`. `'|¶:.B` could work tho.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The challenge description states "_The code input will only contain printable ASCII, and it will not contain any newlines._" Also, what part of the code should be replaced with `'|¶:.B`?

Comment: I was thinking that'd be a shorter split, but it wouldn't work with your current code just slamming it in, you'd have to trim the excess. OR just ignore the excess and `.B` a second time after adding in the preceeding spaces.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn It indeed might save some bytes, since my current work-around is pretty long, but it'll be harder to calculate the amount of preceeding spaces with the spaces after the `.B` already present.

Comment: `'|¶:.BεðÜ}εD®>úsg®+©s}.BεðIJ,`? 29 bytes. Back to iteration 1 :). `.B` splits on newlines, which is a feature not many people know. It's the only way I know of to keep empty elements. I'd request this as a feature. `.¡` should mean split, but keep empty elements..

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks. Indeed didn't knew `.B` implicitly splits on newlines. And using `.¡` as split but keep empty items seems like a nice addition.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

There's a byte to be saved here, *at least*, I just can't quite see it.

```
q| ËùT±DÊÃú Ë+ViS
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=cXwgy/lUsUTKw/ogyytWaVM&input=ImF8YmN8ZHxlfGZnaHxpanxrfGx8bW58b3AiCiIjIg)

```
q| ËùT±DÊÃú Ë+ViS     :Implicit input of strings U=programme & V=character
q|                    :Split U on |
   Ë                  :Map each D
    ù                 :  Left pad with spaces to length
     T±               :    Increment T (initially 0) by
       DÊ             :    Length of D
         Ã            :End map
          ú           :Right pad each with spaces to length of longest
            Ë         :Map
             +        :  Append
              Vi      :    V prepended with
                S     :      Space
                      :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Comment: Wow, this is almost exactly the code I came up, the only difference being that I had `®+S+V` instead of `Ë+ViS`

Comment: [I found that byte you were looking for](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265860/108687) :)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>103</s> 99 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$a-split'\|'|%{" "*$l+$_+" "*(($a-replace'\|').length+1-$_.length-$l)+$b;$l+=$_.Length}
```

Takes input as two strings, `-split`s the first on literal pipe (since split uses regex syntax), and feeds the elements into a loop `|%{...}`.

Each iteration, we construct a string as being a number of spaces defined by `$l` concatenated with the current element. For the first loop, `$l` initializes to `$null`, which gets evaluate here as `0`.

That string is further concatenated with another number of spaces (defined by how long `$a` would be if we `-replace`d every pipe with nothing, plus `1` for the additional padding between code and comments, minus the `.length` of the current element, minus `$l` which is how many spaces we padded left on this iteration), concatenated with our comment character `$b`. That's left on the pipeline.

We then update `$l` for the next iteration.

The resultant strings are all left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program execution, with a newline between them by default.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\esolang-comment-template-generator.ps1 "This|Code|has||empty||sections" "@"
This                     @
    Code                 @
        has              @
                         @
           empty         @
                         @
                sections @

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\esolang-comment-template-generator.ps1 "a|bc|def|ghi|h" "|"
a          |
 bc        |
   def     |
      ghi  |
         h |
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, <s>39</s> 38 keystrokes

-1 byte thanks to DJMcMayhem

Expects as input a buffer (e.g. a file) whose first character is the comment delimiter, followed by the code, e.g. `#foo|bar|baz`.

```
"cxqaf|m`Yp<Ctrl+o>v$r jv0r x@aq@a$p<Ctrl+v>gg$C <Ctrl+r>c<Esc>
```

### Explanation

("`_`" denotes a literal space.)

```
"cx          " Delete the first character (the comment delimiter) and store in register 'c'
qa           " Start recording macro 'a'
f|m`         " Advance to the first '|' on the line and set mark
Yp<Ctrl+o>   " Duplicate this line and return to mark
v$r_         " Replace everything after the cursor on this line (inclusive) with spaces
jv0r_x       " Go down a line and replace everything before the cursor on this line (inclusive) with
             "   spaces, then delete one space
@a           " Call macro recursively
q@a          " Stop recording and immediately call the macro
$p           " Paste the deleted space at the end of the last line
<Ctrl+v>gg$       " Highlight the column where the comment delimiters will go and all trailing spaces
C_<Ctrl+r>c<Esc>  " Replace the highlighted text on each line with a space and the contents of
                  "   register 'c' (the comment delimiter)
```

Comment: :D I always upvote vim! I think you could take one byte off if you change `mm` to `m\`` and then change `\`m` to `<C-o>`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks! I love golfing in Vim because I *always* learn something about a tool I use every day.

Answer (score 2):

## [Floroid](https://github.com/TuukkaX/Floroid) - 94 bytes

```
Ah(a,b):c=a.fn("|");z(" "+b+"\n".y(' '*Z("".y(c[:j]))+l+" "*Z("".y(c[j+1:]))Kj,lIai(c))+' '+b)
```

Uses an approach similar to @[JonathanAllan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)s' Python solution.

### Testcases

```
Call: h("a|bc|d|e|fgh|ij|k|l|mn|op", "#")
Output: 
a                #
 bc              #
   d             #
    e            #
     fgh         #
        ij       #
          k      #
           l     #
            mn   #
              op #
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# <strike>176</strike> <strike>167</strike> 154 bytes

```
string f(string s,char x){var c=s.Split('|');var d="";int i=0;foreach(var b in c)d+=b.PadLeft(i+=b.Length).PadRight(s.Length+2-c.Length)+x+"\n";return d;}
```

UnGolfed

```
string f(string s, char x)
{
    var c = s.Split('|');
    var d = "";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var b in c)
        d += b.PadLeft(i += b.Length).PadRight(s.Length + 2 - c.Length) + x + "\n";
    return d;
}
```

A LINQ solution would have been 146 but needed `using System.Linq;` bringing it back up to 164:

```
string f(string s,char x){var c=s.Split('|');int i=0;return c.Aggregate("",(g,b)=>g+b.PadLeft(i+=b.Length).PadRight(s.Length+2-c.Length)+x+"\n");}
```

Old solutions:

167 bytes:

```
string f(string s,char x){var c=s.Split('|');var d="";int i=0;foreach(var b in c){d+=b.PadLeft(i+b.Length).PadRight(s.Length+2-c.Length)+x+"\n";i+=b.Length;}return d;}
```

176 bytes using string interpolation

```
string f(string s,char x){var c=s.Split('|');var d="";int i=0;foreach(var b in c){d+=string.Format($"{{1,{i}}}{{0,-{s.Length+2-c.Length-i}}}{x}\n",b,"");i+=b.Length;}return d;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 63 bytes

Includes +5 for `-Xpi`

Run with input on STDIN and comment character after -i:

```
perl -Xpi% esolang.pl <<< "Ab|Cd||ef"
```

`esolang.pl`:

```
s/
/|/;s%(.*?)\|%$"x$`=~y/|//c.$1.$"x$'=~y/|//c." $^I
"%eg
```

Totally boring straightforward solution

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṣ”|⁶ṁ;ɗ\pG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//4bmj4oCdfOKBtuG5gTvJl1xwR////1RoaXN8Q29kZXxoYXN8fGVtcHR5fHxzZWN0aW9uc/8nQCc)

Comment: [Explanation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58288160#58288160) by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>107</strike> <strike>104</strike> 103 bytes

```
w=2-(n=split($1,p,"|"))+gsub(t=".",FS,$1){for(;s++<n;gsub(t,FS,b))y=y substr((b=b p[s])$1,1,w)$2RS}$0=y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczRCsIgFIDhVxnihYdZ5G6XEAQ9QOsuupi1mlQqO4ZIp2e3RZc/H/x9upeSdLMQTmN42Ci4kkEyYgD1DV9GRM2WTO46yRW8r34SLdb12rV//IEByDpXc2OchDDaVOGIJ5hPSibgzb778JXOpRxGi7T1l4HGHomGZ4iZCIdztN5htfkC)

*Thanks to Pedro Maimere for helping shave off more 3 chars*

One interesting thing about this challenge...  I found a quirk about the TIO AWK setup.  I can't figure out way to specify input where a positional argument can contain a space.  Meaning setup a TIO test that behaves like this commandline,

```
echo "this is the first parameter" second | gawk '{ print $1 }'
```

In TIO, the first parameter will be `"this` not the whole string.  That means while it works in a terminal window, I can't show that it handle the second test for this challenge in TIO.

Here's how the code works...  The test associated with the codeblock is always truthy, so the code always runs.  It's only a test (rather then code) to avoid needing a `;` character.  It does a couple of things by using AWK's willingness to combine multiple expressions into one "line" of code.

```
w=2-(n=split($1,p,"|"))+gsub(t=".",FS,$1)
```

First is splits the first parameter into in array of strings using the pipe character as the delimeter with `n=split($1,p,"|")`.  It also saves the number of substrings generated in `n`.  Then it changes all the characters in the first parameter to spaces with `gsub(t=".",FS,$1)` setting convenience constants `t` and `n` in the process.

Finally the value of `w` is set to the number of non-pipe characters in the first parameter by subtracting the number of sub-strings from the total number of characters in the original.

The associated code block is one statement, a `for` loop, that processes each substring.

```
for(;s++<n;gsub(t,FS,b))y=y substr((b=b p[s])$1,1,w)$2RS
```

The iteration check is simple `s++<n`. The end of loop statement converts all the characters in the previous output line to blanks `gsub(t,FS,b)`, which turns it into the prefix for the next line.  The body of the loop constructs and appends the next line of output to an accumulator `y`.  That string is a concatenation of the previous string, plus the current string (code fragment) with a bunch of blanks appended (meaning `$1`) `(b=b p[s])$1`.  That mess is truncated to the length we want `w` and the comment delimiter and LF are appended with `y=y substr(...,w)$2RS`.

Once all the code substrings have been processes, assigning `$0` to the accumulator takes care if printing out the results.

```
$0=y
```

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEEDRq5SQRYaOYrutA4LgAaw7cdHUaoPahk6kBMezx4LLz4PfzI@UZipXZiD2TxeMLtCjEgWQ3/ltTSC1VtjSoUZdwOc2TqbiPN8O1Z@xRQsQKWZLcpiMsWQzf@YLLKsCZ9Dlsf7qDcWUTr1j2Y/XTvqGRbqXD1GEuza4ceBs9wM "AWK – Try It Online"). It is having trouble when the code has spaces. I haven't figured out a way to fix that, though.

Comment: I keep forgetting to use FS and RS. :)  Thanks!  The spaces work when I run it from the command line.  Meaning when I run it in a terminal window.  I think it's something about passing tokenized input to AWK in TIO.  I haven't found a way to pass something like `"this is one parameter"` as `$1` in TIO.

Comment: I tried in gawk 5.0.1 and mawk 1.3.3, without success. What version of awk are you using? I also tried another algorithm, but only reached 105 bytes. (_sigh_)

Comment: This works on my system ```echo "E|ac|h s|ecti|on is| one c|haracte|r longer| than the| last!" '!' | gawk 'w=2-(n=split($1,p,"|"))+gsub(t=".",c=FS,$1){for(;s++<n;gsub(t,c,b))y=y substr((b=b p[s])$1,1,w)$2RS}$0=y'``` and it's on Ubuntu 18.04 running `GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)`

Comment: That didn't work either. Well, I modified a bit of your code, and managed to run it on TIO and command-line, [costing 2 more bytes](https://tio.run/##TcyxDoIwFEDRX3k0DG2oBmfsKKODjMahJRWIpCV9NQR8fnvt6HKHM1y9vlLaVXlt5aoO3Clc5inyspaLZMSEqAZ8G86OTLad@Dx94A1W1dk1fy6NEJvaIAvGwLlRBpY7PkTenOQqdrh137JWW0oX0j2NgGT7OJF3MCGBdxay6qD7aCnA7N1gA0EctcuxBLPGWEDxAw). Please check it out, there might be some opportunity to shorten it.

Comment: I will also leave [my own attempt](https://tio.run/##NcuxDoIwEIDhVzkaSNpQEnFn1Im4MKrDSQo0Ni30ahw8n72yuPzDl/z4fubcd20tt84ZP6dFKtXQ6myS9HpQirI86FZvzVFp1IKF@kwhSgLrAdUarU@TqIR09f8fOrzSXSlBlegbJ@jmhR50eTl/cz4xjrwAsRmT5eDBEkPwBnbFiGMyHMEFP5vIkBb0ewyDQ0oFFD8) here, which also has 105 bytes.

Comment: I'd post that one as a separate answer since it's a completely different approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
c=>s=>s.split`|`.map((_,i,a)=>a.map(y=>i--?y.replace(/./g,' '):y).join``+' '+c)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBDsIgFAWvYnBRSAt1aUygR_AIghQqlQKRumjyb-KmMXoob2OjTSZ5mcWbxyvE1sxPy9_30dL956i5yAssJ-9GCZINKmF8qlylCBfqpxMXjtJmYjeTvNIG16zuqmJTkMNEWB9dkLJctNRkze50DDl6w3zssMVoiwhGCs4aWjBguwu4Hq7gYQgQEyLrb57_-wU)

+4 to add an extra space before `#`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 74 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.25 bytes

```
\|/:¦↳:t↲Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqPSIsIiIsIlxcfC86wqbihrM6dOKGsuG4iiIsIiIsIlwidGhlfGZpdG5lc3N8Z3JhbXx8cGFjZXJ8dGVzdFwiXG5cIi8tLVwiIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
01101010100010101110000101000000110001011111111110001111111100110011110001
```

### Explained

```
\|/:¦↳:t↲Ḋ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌­
\|/         # ‎⁡Split on "|"s
   :¦       # ‎⁢Push the cumulative sums without popping. This acts as the space length before each section
     ↳      # ‎⁣Pad each item right with spaces to length in ^
      :t↲   # ‎⁤And pad each item left with spaces to length of tail of ^
         Ḋ  # ‎⁢⁡Append " {comment char}" to each
‎⁢⁢Implicitly join on newlines
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire) and not this challenge.

Comment: You should probably make the Try it Online link have a test case that actually shows the task

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>96</s> 80 bytes

```
->s,c{s.gsub(/(^|\|)([^|]*)/){" "*$`.count(t="^|")+$2+" "*(1+$'.count(t))+c+$/}}
```

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/639012

I really ought to just learn Retina.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>120</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> <s>110</s> 109 bytes

```
foreach($a=split('\|',$argv[1])as$i=>$t){$c=preg_replace('#.#',' ',$a);$c[$i]=$t;echo join($c)," $argv[2]
";}
```

or

```
foreach($a=split('\|',$argv[1])as$t){$c=preg_replace('#.#',' ',$a);$c[$i++|0]=$t;echo join($c)," $argv[2]
";}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
'\|'0'|'hYXo8M&YbY:&YdtaZ)0ihYc
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J1x8JzAnfCdoWVhvOE0mWWJZOiZZZHRhWikwaWhZYw&input=J1RoaXN8Q29kZXxoYXN8fGVtcHR5fHxzZWN0aW9ucycKJyMn)

#### Explanation

The builtin function `Yd` (`blkdiag`), which builds a block-diagonal matrix from its inputs, does most of the work. The fill values in the matrix are 0, and char 0 is treated as a space for displaying purposes. The code would simply split on `|`, build a matrix from the resulting blocks, convert to char, and append two columns with space and comment symbol.

However, the possibility of empty sections in the input string <s>complicates</s> makes the problem more interesting: the resulting block would be empty and thus wouldn't show in the resulting matrix.

To solve this, we introduce a char 0 before each `|`, so no block will be empty; and then in the resulting char matrix we remove columns that are formed by char 0 only. A non-empty code section will have some printable ASCII char, and thus the columns it spans will survive. An empty section will contribute a row, but won't introduce an extra column.

```
'\|'    % Push this string: source for regexp matching. It's just | escaped
0'|'h   % Push a string formed by char 0 followed by | (no escaping needed)
YX      % Input string implicitly. Replace first of the above string by the second
o       % Convert from chars to code points. Gives a numeric vector
8M      % Push '|' again
&Yb     % Split numeric vector at occurences of | (the latter is automatically
        % converted  to its code point). This gives a cell array of numeric vectors
Y:      % Unbox cell array: pushes the numeric vectors it contains
&Yd     % Form a block-diagonal matrix from those vectors
ta      % Duplicate. Compute vector that equals true for columns that have some
        % nonzero value
Z)      % Used that as a logical index (mask) for the columns of the matrix.
        % This removes columns that contain only zeros
0ih     % Input comment symbol and prepend char 0 (which will be displayed as space)
Yc      % Append that to each row of the matrix. The matrix is automatically 
        % converted from code points to chars
        % Display implicitly
```

Comment: I'm vaguely disappointed that you didn't put your explanation in the format the OP mentioned

Comment: @Random832 I don't use that format often. It uses up a lot of space, leaving little room for the explanations

Comment: Why is the escape needed in the first string?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Good question. I never know which/when special symbols need escaping and which/when not. In this case, `|` (_match subexpression before or after the `|`_) does need it, at least in the Matlab/Octave regexp engine

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 bytes

Full program. Prompts for code, then for comment character.

```apl
⍞,⍤1⍨⎕FMT⎕TC[2]@('|'∘=)⍞,' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy9asMwFIV3PcXNUNxCOthxSigUDKbdunkLGWT52g64krG0BM7eLO4WyNSpQ55LL@LKGXyGM3znR/bdc3WSnWkmf/7uJz/@rv34F/vx5n8uH59F8CLfJ4fsMULkz9e3p7kSUTT3J7qrFxIlFCowajRiLRZeqorrRrwuJMUO8RbxC5IN0kQ8LMk7pEJLFqzcEUbT0YKMZgpUDlI5xkCd0Q0PINdKHYxBnbRuJVbLTdGGXW4qDisL8FfvToCdT422IvsH)

`⍞,' '` append a space the to prompted-for code

`⎕TC[2]@(`…`)` place the 2nd Terminal Control character (Line Feed) **at** the positions indicated by:

`'|'∘=` the mask indicating where the pipe symbol is equal to the characters

`⎕FMT` ForMaT as a character matrix, evaluating terminal control characters (Line Feed moves the "cursor" down one line)

`⍞,⍤1⍨` prompt for comment character and append it to each line (lit. to each 1D sub-array)

Comment: How is dyalog APL non-competing still? Is it still in-dev?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes. I work for Dyalog and have had access to 16.0 even before 15.0 was released. 16.0 is scheduled for release in 2017Q1.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Rewritten, and explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 30 bytes

```
VJcE\|s[*ZdN*h--lsJZlNdQ)=+ZlN
```

or

```
jm+dQ.t.t+MC,.u*l+NYdJc+Ed\|kJ
```

Both are full programs that take input on STDIN of the comment string, and then the program string, newline-separated.

[Try the first version online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VJcE%5C%7Cs%5B%2aZdN%2ah--lsJZlNdQ%29%3D%2BZlN&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%27%23%27%0A%22a%7Cbc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cfgh%7Cij%7Ck%7Cl%7Cmn%7Cop%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22Hello%7CWorld%22%0A%22%2C%22%0A%22a%7Cb%7Cc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cf%7Cg%22%0A%22%3A%22%0A%22abcdefg%22%0A%27%25%27%0A%224%7C8%7C15%7C16%7C23%7C42%22%0A%22%21%22%0A%22E%7Cac%7Ch+s%7Cecti%7Con+is%7C+one+c%7Characte%7Cr+longer%7C+than+the%7C+last%21%22%0A%22%40%22%0A%22This%7CCode%7Chas%7C%7Cempty%7C%7Csections%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

[Try the second version online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2BdQ.t.t%2BMC%2C.u%2al%2BNYdJc%2BEd%5C%7CkJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%27%23%27%0A%22a%7Cbc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cfgh%7Cij%7Ck%7Cl%7Cmn%7Cop%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22Hello%7CWorld%22%0A%22%2C%22%0A%22a%7Cb%7Cc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cf%7Cg%22%0A%22%3A%22%0A%22abcdefg%22%0A%27%25%27%0A%224%7C8%7C15%7C16%7C23%7C42%22%0A%22%21%22%0A%22E%7Cac%7Ch+s%7Cecti%7Con+is%7C+one+c%7Characte%7Cr+longer%7C+than+the%7C+last%21%22%0A%22%40%22%0A%22This%7CCode%7Chas%7C%7Cempty%7C%7Csections%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

**How they work**

```
VJcE\|s[*ZdN*h--lsJZlNdQ)=+ZlN  Program. Inputs: E, Q
  cE\|                          Split E on "|"
 J                              Assign to J
                                Implicit Z=0
V                               For N in that:
       [                )        Create a list with elements:
        *Zd                       Z spaces
           N                      N
               -lsJZ              len(concatenate(J))-Z
              -     lN             -len(N)
             h                     +1
            *         d            spaces
                       Q          Q
      s                          Concatenate the list
                                 Implicitly print
                        =+ZlN    Z=Z+len(N)

jm+dQ.t.t+MC,.u*l+NYdJc+Ed\|kJ  Program. Inputs: E, Q
                       +Ed      Add a trailing space to E
                      c   \|    Split that on "|"
                     J          Assign to J
             .u                 Cumulatively reduce J with:
                            k    starting value empty string and
                                 function N, Y ->
                l+NY              len(N+Y)
               *    d             spaces
            ,                J  Two-element list of that and J
           C                    Transpose
         +M                     Map concatenation over that
       .t                       Transpose, padding with spaces
     .t                         Transpose again
 m+dQ                           Map concatenation with Q over that
j                               Join on newlines
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 85 bytes

```
{(;);}:r;", "%(r\(r n+:c;;.,\'|'%.,@\-)):l;0:m;{.,0>}{" "m*\(.,m+:m l\-" "\*+c@}while
```

[Try it online](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=eyg7KTt9OnI7IiwgIiUoclwociBuKzpjOzsuLFwnfCclLixAXC0pKTpsOzA6bTt7LiwwPn17IiAibSpcKC4sbSs6bSBsXC0iICJcKitjQH13aGlsZQ&input=IkhlbGxvLHxXb3JsZCF8VGhpc3xpc3xHb2xmU2NyaXB0IiwgIiMi&debug=on)

## 2017 Update - [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##FccxDsIwDADAnVdYZrCgbgJrIiT@QRhooMU00ArY6ubroUyn64bUfuJbxm8pxEA2Zxd93lvDwUykdJiZj6HeuORPS89258RPhqVyAgmkJqBtrMIfXGGYbSl40SbqVW/adneVh/aa9PnSYUQGXOMP) - 71 bytes

```
', '/~~:c;~1/.,\.{'|'=},,@\-):l;['|']/0:i;{.,i+:i l i-' '*c+\' '*"
"\}/
```

#### Explanation

```
', '/~~:c;~1/        # Parses input
.,\.{'|'=},,@\-):l;  # Computes string length without '|'
['|']/               # Splits the array
0:i;                 # Counter
{.,                  # Length of the substring
i+:i                 # Counter update
l i-' '*c+\          # Adds spaces after the substring 
' '*"\n"\            # Adds spaces before the next substring
}/                   # ...For each substring
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), 35 bytes (noncompeting)

Takes one input, the last character is the comment character. Does not work with comment character as space, but I assume that isn't necessary.

```
!' [*.+(|' dl)r_]' r[*+.(|u)_][ .d]
```

Explanation:

```
!                                  take input into string variable
 '                                 write space over current cell
   [*           ]                  while cell is not *
     .+                            write pointed char of string, stringpointer+1 (starts 0)
       (|    )                     if current cell is |
         ' dl                      write space (over |), move down, left
              r_                   move right, write * if pointed char is
                                   last char, else space

                 ' r               write space, move right
                    [*       ]     while cell is not *
                      +.           increment pointer and write pointed char
                        (|u)       if cell is |, move up
                            _      write * if the pointed char is the last char

                              [   ] while cell is not space
                                .d  write the pointed char from string, move down
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 89 bytes

```
s=>c=>{y=0forn inl=s::split"|"print((v=" "::rep)(y)+l[n]+v((#l::reduce@++1)-y+=#l[n])+c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDdasIwFL62T3GMCA3twDo3RiUiyN7AO@lFTE@1rKZdE4XS02fvUlc2mCwXB/L9JefLrvqj6TPRG7FRYtM2YpGVtYZcF8LEsamK3DJiVZ1r6/s3wYDFcY0V9xseFAedBDffnxUDll4VboMg4k9NIGYDxwPFu36Pxu6kQQMCWm/SMklHUpQSUkYnFgILWRfeiaNKMbtD8Qit6I2iF4peaflMq@VAzUfqnaSiMxhCZXMq3Z8NQakRHCprqSxSDUWpT1gT2LPUbiBBIY2dDjnTMWd/dsZdmaKzGSK8VLYhMkNqqc2g3LLO6zzPFQO5awZ@N2o9GM93Q2z@6fpxwou0/o/skCeHRcLD/9ko4XztTbIHz4Ns/edF/nDv@i8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 108 bytes

```python
s,c=input().split("|"),input()
i,S=0,len("".join(s))
for l in s:L=len(l);print(" "*i+l+" "*(S-L-i+1)+c);i+=L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsIwEADvfUXIKWvSonizBApee6sfkBrpStyEbjwU9u/RgqeBGSZvZUl0rpXd7JHypxjoOEcsRosG91cNuskfXQxktO5eCckwQPNMq4oKSfFl9HuM0OcV6TcrfUAb7U4ztWOL9gR2hh6tH2u9LchyTY8gy51FwjuXTYTDXDARN8MX) Simple solution -- keep track of how many spaces we have (i) and accumulate.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.8 (pre-release), 99 bytes

Different approach:

```
def f(c,d,i=0):
 for y in(x:=c.split('|')):z=[' '*len(e)for e in x];z[i]=y;print(''.join(z),d);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHNasMwEITvfoqNS5GVuCF/LcHBUCh9g97SUBR5HSu1JWPpEId9d1eqQy657GH2m9EyantXGb3ett0wFFhCmci0SFW@4FkEpemgB6WTS5bLuW1r5RJGjPPsmu8ZsGmNOkEeMPQYXA67614d8n7Xdkp7ls3PxtuvPC34Ts3y5eDQOiksWshhHyWxoKOkgpDKU0XqTL9UU6PJtHEK8VPM05GhG0SnoKc3/Sj9yf9KNiob2tLylZZvtFrTZhU2z@Pmk4SkCiyhdIqMBmUJjEbwquiEdEgd1EafsCNwldB@IEEtrJuEmMkY81V534cp0LssETat64lsCDXaBvA95tEhikIn0nOpn02D2v1I/04o6d6AL/hW0wubbhcz9q0Zj8IPPPj4HWV8@AM)

Ungolfed with explanation:

```
def f(c,d,i=0):
 x=c.split('|')              # break string by '|'
 for y in x:                 # for each element of list
  z=[' '*len(e) for e in x]  # create a list of blank strings
  z[i]=y                     # insert element we care about into otherwise blank list
  print(''.join(z),d)        # print line
  i+=1                       # increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ù3l╛CrΣ╝▀↕┘╣óétº
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=97336cbe4372e4bcdf12d9b9a28274a7&i=%22,%22,+%22a%7Cb%7Cc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cf%7Cg%22%0A%22%23%22,+%22a%7Cbc%7Cd%7Ce%7Cfgh%7Cij%7Ck%7Cl%7Cmn%7Cop%22&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 209 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(C,c string)string{L,Q,S:=Split(C,"|"),[]string{},0
for _,l:=range L{q:=len(l)
if q<1{continue}
Q=append(Q,Repeat(" ",S)+l+Repeat(" ",len(Join(L,""))-q+1-S)+c)
S+=q}
return Join(Q,"\n")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVFNjtMwFBZbn-KNUaVYddF0GNAoIghpxAZ1QSm7tkKu66RmEjuJnQXKi8Q92FRIHIJjsITTYDcBjWTZft_3vf9v3wt7_lkL-SAKBZXQhuiqtq1_RvPK0x-dzxd3v3_9w5xvtSkcJXlnJOTJPZcwYmx8-hVf802abepS-0BTpIxv9xM58GuS2xY-8TLNWmFCylXfpFmpTFIyonNoXi17aY3XplMDWWeirpU5Jmv-QdVK-IQC5Rs2L-eP7Oj9zmqTrDiljC2a-XIRNJKRzTxrBtIq37UGLpI1pztD2TA29ufJ10sjse-EQU-0qTvvIM1gu_9fNempwANKPKLCHAvKQ1I68Igf5FHlFyQdkVu8w-ULXL7Em-d4exOZ2ci8RSHxBA6V9BqtAe0QrFEQUNEK6RW2UNowlBbBn4QJl0IohfNXMczVGObjKfjd26MKXg5RVbX_guhiUGtcFL6ZasPDVHJxQv0ZH7DEyqCto-Zp1Axk2oaKHY_7mCbQExlSRFhtr_fBqCpl_Ggv98R2l3-eRBWHiWbkfRiYzxM6ayCc7PXOzNzOhIlHzSMlhxCBhQKmRZzP4_sX)

#### Explanation

```go
import."strings"
func f(C,c string)string{
// split C into substrings, and init the output slice and space count
L,Q,S:=Split(C,"|"),[]string{},0
// for each substring...
for _,l:=range L{
// if it's empty, skip it
q:=len(l)
if q<1{continue}
// add to the output slice...
Q=append(Q,
    // initial spaces
    Repeat(" ",S)+
    // the substring
    l+
    // the following spaces 
    Repeat(" ",len(Join(L,""))-q+1-S)
    // and the comment    
    +c)
// increment the space count
S+=q}
// join together with newlines
return Join(Q,"\n")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>84</s> 79 bytes

```javascript
c=>s=>s.split`|`.map(l=>z="".padEnd(a=z.length)+l,z="").map(l=>l.padEnd(a+2)+c)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3_ZNt7YqBSK-4ICezJKEmQS83sUAjx9auylZJSa8gMcU1L0Uj0bZKLyc1L70kQ1M7RwckowlTlgNXo22kqZ2sCTVWJzk_rzg_J1UvJz9dI01DSVlJU0MpMSm5JqWmJjWtJr0mA2hEVn5mXgJXAlTPggUQGgA)

Saved 5 bytes by using two iterations instead of 1 but keeping track of the previous string so no number is needed to keep track of the length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
q| åÏiXîÃú m+S+V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=cXwg5c9pWO7D%2biBtK1MrVg&input=IjR8OHwxNXwxNnwyM3w0MiIsICIlIg)

The boilerplate is similar to [@Shaggy's 17 byte Japt submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264570/108687).

Explanation:

```
q|                 split on |
   åÏ              cumulatively reduce each X, Y to:
     i               prepend to Y
      Xî             spaces to the length of X
        Ã          end cumulative reduce
         ú         right-pad each to the longest line
           m+      to each, append
             S+V     space (S) and comment char (V)

flag -R            join the final result on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```ruby
->i,c{a=0;(i=i.split ?|).map{" "*a+_1+" "*(1+i.join.size-(a+=_1.size))+c}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboWN7107TJ1kqsTbQ2sNTJtM_WKC3IySxTsazT1chMLqpUUlLQSteMNtUEMDUPtTL2s_Mw8veLMqlRdjURt23hDMFtTUzu5thZi4t6C0pJihbRopcSk5JqU1LSa9IyazKzsHCUdJWWlWIiaBQsgNAA)

I managed to golf a non-regex based solution to beat the other Ruby. The solution previously tied but I found a slightly different method that is 6 bytes shorter.

Explanation:

`->i,c{…}` Proc (lambda function) taking arguments `i` (code) and `c` (comment)

- `a=0;` Assign variable `a` to zero
- `(i=i.split ?|)` Assign `i` to it split on `|`
- `.map{…}` Map each `_1` in the list to:

  - `" "*a` `a` spaces
  - `+_1` Append the list item
  - `+" "*(…)` Append this many spaces:

    - `1+i.join.size` The size of `i` with `|` removed, plus one for the extra space
    - `-(a+=_1.size)` Add the size of the list item to `a` and subtract `a` from this.
  - `+c` Append the comment character to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 96 bytes

```haskell
f"".lines.map r
r '|'='\n'
r c=c
w=(' '<$)
f l(a:s)c=(w l++a++(w=<<c:s)++c):f(l++a)s c
f l s c=s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZDPSgMxEMbxuk8xjcrusm2ltUopXRBE8OJJwUNbMM1m_9hssiRZSmHexEsvpb6SPo1Ju14yw--bbz4mX8eSmg0X4ntBBqxpyOpQQArLQ2vzwfTnIydkKCrJzbCmDehAQ4hhGi5l6FqWsmCbRiGE86s4yEFEdGZilkZbEElCkyTapvM5cyxJWDzLI09jA8zPgqupOef8XpCaVtIFu5QXiJrWvloNQ2jlKfzUsVbrHRQQwyKAiFBcM8yQY16UWH3iBgXWElVD-kAuSdz3Q8_uMoXvSovM45sOOy92Ziy80P8X1izj-QnNOjTBKY7ucHSP41ucjL103UlPSBmWYJAzW6GSUBkEJTk4SjVllqMGoWTBNYItqXQPRxDU2J7f0-v2vJXO-Kgy7mwGkdeN3SEav1VJ4ycfSLw6f9V-f65_)

##### Eplanation

The function `r` is defined to map pipe characters to newlines (`r '|'='\n'`) and every other char to itself (`r c=c`). `lines.map r` thus first replaces all pipes in the input string with new lines (`map r`), and then splits the string at the newlines with the build-in `lines` function.
The main function `f` iterates over this list of strings and constructs the output line by line with the expression `w l++a++(w=<<c:s)++c` where

- `a` is the part of the code that appears on the current line
- `c` is the comment character (as a string) that gets put at the end of the line
- `w` is a function that replaces each character of a string by spaces (definde by `w=(' '<$)`)
- `l` is the string of code fragments to the left of `a`, which is put at the beginnig of the line as spaces with `w l`
- `s` is the list of remaining code strings which are also converted to spaces, concatenated, and put after `a` (`c` is added to `s` to get the extra space required before the comment character)

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
≡⊂⬚@ ≡°□\⍚(⊂≡⋅@ )⊕□⍜▽¯⟜\+=,@|:¤⊟@
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4omh4oqC4oqZKOKGr3ziip9AICnin5zip7virJpAIOKJocKw4pahXOKNmijiioLihq86QCDip7sp4oqV4pah4o2c4pa9wq_in5xcKz0sQHwKCkYgImJhYXxiY3xkfGV8ZmdofHxpanxrfGx8bW58b3AiIEAjCg==)

-2 bytes thanks to chunes :)

This was one of my first Uiua answers, I got so much better in only 2 weeks, and was able to save 10%!

Comment: [-2](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4omh4oqC4oqZKOKGr3ziip9AICnin5zip7virJpAIOKJocKw4pahXOKNmijiioLihq86QCDip7sp4oqV4pah4o2c4pa9wq_in5xcKz0sQHwKCkYgImJhYXxiY3xkfGV8ZmdofHxpanxrfGx8bW58b3AiIEAjCg==) since `⊙(F⊙(G))` is equivalent to `⊙(F|G)`.

Comment: @chunes Cool! So many neat features I haven’t seen yet

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 50 bytes

```perl
$f=<>;s%\||$%$"x$'=~y/|//c." $f
".$"x$`=~y/|//c%ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lzdbGzrpYNaamRkVVRalCRd22rlK/Rl8/WU9JQSWNS0kPJJgAE1RNT/3/P7EmKbkmpSa1Ji09oyYzqya7JqcmN68mv4BL@V9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugU5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 123 bytes

```
def?(i:String,c:String)={var b=0
i.split('|').map{s=>println(" "*b+s+" "*(i.replace("|","").size-b-s.size+1)+c)
b+=s.size}}
```

Test code + Output:

```
?("a|b|c|d|e|f|g", ",")
a       ,
 b      ,
  c     ,
   d    ,
    e   ,
     f  ,
      g ,

?("abcdefg", ":")
abcdefg :

?("4|8|15|16|23|42", "%")
4          %
 8         %
  15       %
    16     %
      23   %
        42 %

?("E|ac|h s|ecti|on is| one c|haracte|r longer| than the| last!", "!")
E                                                   !
 ac                                                 !
   h s                                              !
      ecti                                          !
          on is                                     !
                one c                               !
                     haracte                        !
                            r longer                !
                                     than the       !
                                              last! !

?("This|Code|has||empty||sections", "@")
This                     @
    Code                 @
        has              @
                         @
           empty         @
                         @
                sections @
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

This looks like it has far to many increments, and probably too many links...

```
ṫø⁹‘‘µFL‘⁶ẋ
‘ị
ḣFL⁶ẋ$;ç@;1ŀ
J’ç@€
ṣ”|Ç;€Y
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmrw7jigbnigJjigJjCtUZM4oCY4oG24bqLCuKAmOG7iwrhuKNGTOKBtuG6iyQ7w6dAOzHFgApK4oCZw6dA4oKsCuG5o-KAnXzDhzvigqxZ&input=&args=IlRoaXN8Q29kZXxoYXN8fGVtcHR5fHxzZWN0aW9ucyI+IkAi)

How?

```
ṫø⁹‘‘µFL‘⁶ẋ  - link 1: get the spaces for after the code, dyadic(split string, index)
 ø           - next chain as a nilad
  ⁹‘‘        - right argument incremented twice (the index we actually want)
ṫ            - tail (get the rest of the split string)
     µ       - next chain as a monad
      FL‘    - flatten, get its length and increment
         ⁶   - a space character " "
          ẋ  - repeat the space character that many times

‘ị           - Link 2: get the code for a line dyadic(index, split string)
‘            - increment the index
 ị           - retrieve the string at that index

ḣFL⁶ẋ$;ç@;1ŀ - Link 3: get the code and join with spaces, dyadic (index, split string)
ḣ            - head: split string[index:]
 FL          - flatten and get its length
     $       - previous two atoms as a monad
   ⁶         - a space character, " "
    ẋ        - repeat the space that many times
      ;      - concatenate with
       ç@    - the result of the previous link (the code) - reverse inputs
         ;   - concatenate with
          1ŀ - the result of Link 1 (the spaces after the code)

J’ç@€        - Link 3: a for loop, monadic(split string)
J’           - [0,...,Len(split string)-1]
  ç@€        - the result of the previous link, with revered inputs, for each

ṣ”|Ç;€Y      - Main Link: dyadic(code string, comment character)
ṣ”|          - split on "|"
   Ç         - the result of the previous link
    ;€       - concatenate each with the comment character
      Y      - join with line feeds
             - implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 32 bytes

```
l'|/_s,)L@{1$,S*\+}%@f{Se]}lN+f+
```

Explanation

```
l                                  get code string
 '|/                               split into code parts
    _s,)                           length of all the parts +1
        L@{1$,S*\+}%               left pad spaces to every part for the length of the previous parts
                    @f{Se]}        right pad spaces
                           lN+f+   add comment character and newline
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bCd8L19zLClMQHsxJCxTKlwrfSVAZntTZV19bE4rZis&input=VGhpc3xDb2RlfGhhc3x8ZW1wdHl8fHNlY3Rpb25zCkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'|/DJl⁺X0Yıyṣs+xðĿnlẏ+ƥ¹+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSclN0MlMkZESmwlRTIlODElQkFYMFklQzQlQjF5JUUxJUI5JUEzcyUyQnglQzMlQjAlQzQlQkZubCVFMSVCQSU4RiUyQiVDNiVBNSVDMiVCOSUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMkUlN0NhYyU3Q2glMjBzJTdDZWN0aSU3Q29uJTIwaXMlN0MlMjBvbmUlMjBjJTdDaGFyYWN0ZSU3Q3IlMjBsb25nZXIlN0MlMjB0aGFuJTIwdGhlJTdDJTIwbGFzdCElMjIlMEElMjIhJTIyJmZsYWdzPU4=)

##### Explanation

*(Yes, this is in the exact same format as the outputs for this challenge :P)*

```python
'|/DJl⁺X0Yıyṣs+xðĿnlẏ+ƥ¹+  '# Implicit input
'|/                        '# Split the input on "|"
   DJl                      # Duplicate, join, and get length
      ⁺X                    # Increment this and store it in x
        0Y                  # Store 0 in y
          ı                 # Map over the list:
           yṣ               #  Push y spaces
             s+             #  Prepend this to the input
               xðĿ          #  Pad with spaces to length x
                  nlẏ+ƥ     #  Add the length to y
                       ¹+   #  Append the second input
                            # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```
~:~;"|"/[""\{\," "*\+.}/,):l;]{l" "*+l<~n}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86qzlqpRkk/WkkppjpGR0lBSStGW69WX0fTKsc6tjoHJKCdY1OXV6v//79SYlJyTUpqWk1NegZQQlkJA)

This was my first GolfScript submission, and I’ve improved quite a lot since I first tried this task.

Explanation:

```
~:~;
```

Eval STDIN as GolfScript. Assign the comment character to the `~` variable, and pop out of the stack, so the code is on top.

Using a symbol instead of a letter as a command name let me remove a whitespace later on.

```
"|"/
```

Split the code on `|`s.

```
[""\{\," "*\+.}/
```

This is equivalent to a scan (reduce, keeping in-between values) by repeating spaces to the length of the previous value, and prepending that to the current value.

GolfScript doesn’t have scan built-in, so this is implemented somewhat cumbersomely, using `/` (each) and duplicating the result each iteration.

```
,):l;]
```

The previous step left an extra copy of the last value. We take its length, increment that, and assign it to `l`.

```
{l" "*+l<~n}/
```

For each line (`{ … }/`): append `l` spaces (`l" "*+`), take the first `l` characters (`l<`), then push `~` (the comment character) and `n` (newline).

The entire stack is printed when the program ends.

Original solution:

### [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
~n+:c;0:a;."|"/""*,):b;{.124={;b" "*c" "a*}{a):a;b(:b;}if}%" "c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYrLCoAgEAB/JRaCtLAHnVz6GN3Sgqiobmq/bnuZw8z4c3cP3dv15vwdtSbstEEFEVoA2QhtMah@GKeAFgqQxDAyBSN4sxXntLlUsqWcwViK8@KiX1kg/A)

Full program, takes input like `"abc|def|g" "#"` on STDIN.

I’ve always thought GolfScript seemed interesting but have never actually tried it. After using quite a few more modern golfing languages with hundreds of built-ins, the terse but very readable syntax of GolfScript is really refreshing. I had a lot of fun trying to get this to work, so I’m glad I could beat the 75 byte solution posted in 2017.

I had a 50-or so byte version that used stack manipulation instead of variables, but couldn’t get it to work.

I hope you like the smileys `):` `(:` `:b` `:c` `={`

### Explanation

Eval the input; this leaves two strings on the stack. Append a newline to the top one, store it in `c` as the comment character, and pop it off the stack. The variable `a` is initialized to 0. The variable `b` is initialized to the length of splitting the input on `|` and joining it back.

The top of the stack is now the `|`-separated string. Map each character of the input string to:

- If the character is `|`, leave `b` spaces, `c`, a newline, and `a` spaces on the stack.
- Otherwise, increment `a`, decrement `b`, and leave the original character in the stack.

Finally, push a space and `c` to the stack. The whole stack is implicitly output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, <s>153</s> 152 bytes

```swift
let f={var x={{String.init}()(" ",$0)},s=($0+"").split{$0=="|"},i=0
return{s.map{x(i)+$0+x(s.joined().count-(i+=$0.count,i).1+1)}.joined}()($1+"\n")+$1}
```

This is an almost direct port of [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92785/118665). Here's an ungolfed version:

```swift
let function = { (code: String, comment: String) -> String in
  // convenience closure to repeat the space character
  let spaces = { String(repeating: " ", count: $0) }
  
  // split the code into substrings using the pipe as
  // a separator
  let splitCode = code.split(separator: "|")

  var indentLevel = 0

  let indentedCode = splitCode.map { line in
    // start off with the previous indent level
    let leadingIndent = spaces(indentLevel)

    // update the indent level for the trailing indent
    // and the next leading indent
    indentLevel += line.count

    // gets the total length of the code, subtracts the
    // current indent level, and adds 1 for an extra
    // trailing space
    let trailingIndentAmount = splitCode.joined().count - indentLevel + 1
    let trailingIndent = spaces(trailingIndentAmount)

    return leadingIndent + line + trailingIndent + comment
  }

  // finally, join the code with newlines and return it
  return indentedCode.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lF\| -M5.10.0`, 31 bytes

A different approach to both [the existing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271641/9365) [Perl answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92988/9365).

```perl
$,=v12;say@F," .[A@{[<>]}.."x@F
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJCw9djEyO3NheUBGLFwiIFx1MDAxYltBQHtbPD5dfVxiXGJcInhARiIsImFyZ3MiOiItbEZcXHxcbi1NNS4xMC4wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiJhfGJ8Y3xkfGV8ZnxnXG4sIn0=)

### Explanation

Sets `$,` (which is the record separator, automatically printed between each item of a list) to `v12` (which is `chr(12)`, or form feed - which moves the cursor down a line), then we `say` `@F` (which is the input, split on `|`), followed by a raw string consisting of space, the ANSI escape sequence for "up one line", the comment char from STDIN (`<>`), which is embedded to the string using `@{[...]}`, and two backspace characters, which is repeated the same number of times as there are items in the input (using the list of input, `@F`, in a scalar context yield the list length).