# Parse the comments out of my esoteric code

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, comment

Earlier this week, we learned about how to [format esoteric languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92776/esolang-comment-template-generator) for commenting. Today, we're going to do the inverse of that. I need you to write a program or function that parses some well-commented esoteric code and parses the comments out, returning just the code. Using some examples from the previous challenge, here is what well-commented code looks like:

```
a                #Explanation of what 'a' does
 bc              #Bc
   d             #d
    e            #Explanation of e
     fgh         #foobar
        ij       #hello world
          k      #etc.
           l     #so on
            mn   #and
              op #so forth
```

Here is what you need to do to extract the code out. First, remove the comment character (`#`), the space before it, and everything after the comment character.

```
a               
 bc             
   d            
    e           
     fgh        
        ij      
          k     
           l    
            mn  
              op
```

Then, collapse each line upwards into a single line. For example, since `b` is in the second column on line two, once we collapse it up, it will be in the second column on line *one*. Similarly, `c` will be put in the third column of line one, and `d` will be put on the fourth. Repeat this for every character, and you get this:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

Important note: It seems like the trivial solution is to just remove the comments, remove every space, and join every line. This is *not* a valid approach! Because the original code might have spaces in it, these will get stripped out with this approach. For example, this is a perfectly valid input:

```
hello         #Line one
              #Line two
       world! #Line three
```

And the corresponding output should be:

```
hello  world!
```

## The Challenge:

Write a program or function that takes commented code as input, and outputs or returns the code with all the comments parsed out of it. You should output the code *without* any trailing spaces, although one trailing newline is permissible. The comment character will always be `#`, and there will always be one extra space before the comments start. `#` will *not* appear in the comment section of the input. In order to keep the challenge simpler, here are some inputs you do *not* have to handle:

- You can assume that the code will not have two characters in the same column. For example, this is an input that violates this rule:

  ```
  a  #A character in column one
  bc #Characters in columns one and two
  ```
- You can also assume that all comment characters appear in the same column. For example, this input:

  ```
  short       #this is a short line
        long        #This is a long line
  ```

  violates this rule. This also means that `#` will not be in the code section.
- And lastly, you do not have to handle code sections with leading or trailing spaces. For example,

  ```
    Hello,          #
           World!   #
  ```

You may also assume that the input only contains printable ASCII characters.

## Examples:

```
Input:
hello         #Line one
              #Line two
       world! #Line three

Output:
hello  world!

Input:
E                                                   #This comment intentionally left blank
 ac                                                 #
   h s                                              #
      ecti                                          #
          on is                                     #
                one c                               #
                     haracte                        #
                            r longer                #
                                     than the       #
                                              last! #

Output:
Each section is one character longer than the last!

Input:
4          #This number is 7
 8         #
  15       #That last comment is wrong.
    16     #
      23   #
        42 #

Output:
4815162342

Input:
Hello                     #Comment 1
      world               #Comment 2
           ,              #Comment 3
             how          #Comment 4
                 are      #Comment 5
                     you? #Comment 6

Output:
Hello world, how are you?

Input:
Prepare                               #
        for...                        #
                        extra spaces! #

Output:
Prepare for...          extra spaces!
```

You may take input in whatever reasonable format you like, for example, a list of strings, a single string with newlines, a 2d list of characters, etc. The shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Will we need to accept code with characters *lower* than the next?

Comment: Could you add the test case with the empty line with just two spaces (like the `hello  world!` you've showed)? Also, you state: "_`#` will not appear in the comment section of the input._", but can it occur in the code-snippet itself?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen See my edits

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not sure if I understand your question

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Example: `do {stuff} while (condition);` with the explanation in order `do         while (condition); #Explainything` then `{stuff} #Explainything`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm pretty sure that's covered under `You can assume that the code will not have two characters in the same column`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem The HTML parser on your / my browser stripped the whitespace. Imagine a gap inbetween `while` and `(condition)`, and a gap before / after `{stuff}`. (I'm not very good at explaining, am I?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
»/ṣ”#ḢṖ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrsv4bmj4oCdI-G4ouG5lgrhu7TDhyAgICAgIOG4t-KAnCBTcGxpdCBhdCBuZXdsaW5lcyBhbmQgY2FsbCB0aGUgbGluayBhYm92ZS4&input=&args=SGVsbG8gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjQ29tbWVudCAxCiAgICAgIHdvcmxkICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI0NvbW1lbnQgMgogICAgICAgICAgICwgICAgICAgICAgICAgICNDb21tZW50IDMKICAgICAgICAgICAgIGhvdyAgICAgICAgICAjQ29tbWVudCA0CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYXJlICAgICAgI0NvbW1lbnQgNQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB5b3U_ICNDb21tZW50IDY)

#### How it works

```
»/ṣ”#ḢṖ  Main link. Argument: A (array of strings)

»/       Reduce the columns of A by maximum.
         Since the space is the lowest printable ASCII characters, this returns the
         non-space character (if any) of each column.
  ṣ”#    Split the result at occurrences of '#'.
     Ḣ   Head; extract the first chunk, i.e., everything before the (first) '#'.
      Ṗ  Pop; remove the trailing space.
```

Comment: That is just ...wow.

Comment: I am so jelly right now.

Comment: How do you even hack that into your phone?

Comment: @simbabque Patience and a lot of copy-pasting.

Comment: I'm always putting using a 9-iron, maybe it's time I learned how to use a putter when on the green...

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, <s>48</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda x:`map(max,*x)`[2::5].split(' #')[0]
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 5 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/UslRUT).

Comment: I think you can just do `map(max,*x)` because `max` takes any number of arguments and `None` is small.

Comment: Right, I always forget that `map` can be used like that... Thanks!

Comment: How does the `\`...\`[2::5]` trick work?

Comment: @smls `\`...\`` is equivalent to `repr(...)`, so for the list of singleton strings `['a', 'b', 'c']`, you get the string `"['a', 'b', 'c']"`. Finally, `[2::5]` chops off the first two characters (`"['"`) and takes every fifth character of the remaining string.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>97</s> <s>75</s> 60 bytes

Thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for helping golf off 22 bytes

```
a=>a.reduce((p,c)=>p.replace(/ /g,(m,o)=>c[o])).split` #`[0]
```

Input is an array of lines.

- `a` is array input
- `p` is previous item
- `c` is current item
- `m` is match string
- `o` is offset

Comment: I count 96 bytes? Also, the `m` regexp flag is unnecessary (did you have a `$` at one point?) as is the space in `(p, c)`. Finally, I think `replace` will work out shorter than `[...p].map().join`.

Comment: 97 for me, both from manual `length` and userscript, maybe you didn't count the newline, but only because I accidentally included the semicolon

Comment: I see now - I hadn't copied the `;` which isn't required (JavaScript has ASI).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had it to make sure Chromium console puts the function call outside the function body (had it once on a badly written lambda)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realise `replace` would help so much, that's really neat!

Comment: Isn't there a `g` missing at the end of the first regex?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Try it, it works perfectly fine, plus I explain its absence right after the snippet

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN

`eso.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
y/ /\0/;/.#/;$\|=$`}{$\=~y;\0;
```

Notice that there is a space after the final `;`. The code works as shown, but replace `\0` by the literal character to get the claimed score.

Comment: Very nice code. That `$a|=...` is rather well done, it took me a while to figure out what you were doing! One question though : `*_=a` seems to be roughly equivalent to `$_=$a`, why is that?

Comment: `*_=a` is a very obscure glob assignment which aliases the `_` globals and the `a` globals. So it's not so much a copy from `$a` to `$_` but from that point on (global) `$a` and `$_` are actually the same variable. All to save 1 byte...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! (and nice improvement thanks to `$\\`)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 187 bytes

```
def f(x,o=""):
 l=[i[:i.index("#")-1]for i in x]
 for n in range(len(l[0])):
  c=[x[n]for x in l]
  if sum([1for x in c if x!=" "])<1:o+=" "
  else:o+=[x for x in c if x!=" "][0]
 print o
```

I'm gonna golf this more tomorrow I have school ;)

Comment: `1 for` can be reduced to `1for`. Also, if the sum of the list (at line 5) can't be negative, you can just check for `<1` instead of `==0`. Happy school day! :D +1.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 30 bytes

```
(#~[:<./\'#'~:])@(>./&.(3&u:))
```

Takes a list of strings as input. Basically uses the same approach as Dennis in his Jelly answer.

### Commented and explained

```
ord =: 3 & u:
under =: &.
max =: >./
over =: @
maxes =: max under ord
neq =: ~:
arg =: ]
runningMin =: <./\
magic =: #~ [: runningMin ('#' neq arg)

f =: magic over maxes
```

Intermediate steps:

```
   p
Hello                     #Comment 1
      world               #Comment 2
           ,              #Comment 3
             how          #Comment 4
                 are      #Comment 5
                     you? #Comment 6
   maxes p
Hello world, how are you? #Comment 6
   magic
#~ ([: runningMin '#' neq arg)
   3 neq 4
1
   '#' neq '~'
1
   '#' neq '#'
0
   '#' neq maxes p
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   runningMin 5 4 2 5 9 0 _3 4 _10
5 4 2 2 2 0 _3 _3 _10
   runningMin '#' neq maxes p
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 1 1 0 # 'abcdef'
bde
   'abcdef' #~ 0 1 0 1 1 0
bde
   (maxes p) #~ runningMin '#' neq maxes p
Hello world, how are you? 
   (#~ [: runningMin '#' neq arg) maxes p
Hello world, how are you? 
   ((#~ [: runningMin '#' neq arg) over maxes) p
Hello world, how are you? 
   (magic over maxes) p
Hello world, how are you?
```

### Test case

```
   f =: (#~[:<./\'#'~:])@(>./&.(3&u:))
   a
Hello                     #Comment 1
      world               #Comment 2
           ,              #Comment 3
             how          #Comment 4
                 are      #Comment 5
                     you? #Comment 6
   $a
6 36
   f a
Hello world, how are you?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 63 bytes

Basically a port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93068/11261). Takes input as an array of strings.

```
->a{l,=a
l.gsub(/./){a.map{|m|m[$`.size]||$/}.max}[/(.+) #/,1]}
```

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/640757

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 12 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 2 bytes.*

```
{:.e>_'##(<}
```

An unnamed block that takes a list of strings (one for each line) and replaces it with a single string.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WyJoZWxsbyAgICAgICAgICNMaW5lIG9uZSIKICIgICAgICAgICAgICAgICNMaW5lIHR3byIKICIgICAgICAgd29ybGQhICNMaW5lIHRocmVlIl0KCns6LmU-XycjIyg8fQoKfg&input=aGVsbG8gICAgICAgICAjTGluZSBvbmUKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjTGluZSB0d28KICAgICAgIHdvcmxkISAjTGluZSB0aHJlZQ)

#### Explanation

```
:.e>  e# Reduce the list of strings by elementwise maximum. This keeps non-spaces in
      e# favour of spaces. It'll also wreak havoc with the comments, but we'll discard
      e# those anyway.
_'##  e# Duplicate and find the index of '#'.
(<    e# Decrement that index and truncate the string to this length.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), 63 bytes

```js
a=>a.reduce((p,c)=>p+/(.+?)\s+#/.exec(c)[1].slice(p.length),'')
```

Takes input as an array of strings.

```js
F=a=>a.reduce((p,c)=>p+/(.+?)\s+#/.exec(c)[1].slice(p.length),'')

input.oninput = update;
update();

function update() {
  try {
    output.innerHTML = F(input.value.trim().split`
`);
  } catch(e) {
    output.innerHTML = 'ERROR: INVALID INPUT';
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<h2>Input:</h2>
<textarea id="input" rows="8">
a                #Explanation of what 'a' does
 bc              #Bc
   d             #d
    e            #Explanation of e
     fgh         #foobar
        ij       #hello world
          k      #etc.
           l     #so on
            mn   #and
              op #so forth
</textarea>
<hr />
<h2>Output:</h2>
<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 32 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
Rmr` #.+|(?<=^(?<-1>.)+).+?¶( )+
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Um1yYCAjLit8KD88PV4oPzwtMT4uKSspLis_wrYoICkr&input=YSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjRXhwbGFuYXRpb24gb2Ygd2hhdCAnYScgZG9lcwogYmMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICNCYwogICBkICAgICAgICAgICAgICNkCiAgICBlICAgICAgICAgICAgI0V4cGxhbmF0aW9uIG9mIGUKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjZm9vYmFyCiAgICAgICAgaWogICAgICAgI2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI2V0Yy4KICAgICAgICAgICBsICAgICAjc28gb24KICAgICAgICAgICAgbW4gICAjYW5kCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgb3AgI3NvIGZvcnRo)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>15</s> 10 bytes

```
,FSe)s\#ch
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2CFSe%29s%5C%23ch&input=%22Prepare+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+comment+1%22%2C%22++++++++for...++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+comment+2%22%2C%22++++++++++++++++++++++++extra+spaces%21+%23+comment+3%22)

Port of the Jelly answer

```
,          -     transpose()
 FSe)      -    map(min, ^)
     s     -   sum(^)
      \#c  -  ^.split("#")
         h - ^[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# <strike>157</strike> 122 Bytes

Golfed 35 bytes thanks to @milk -- though I swear I tried that earlier.

Takes input as a 2-d array of characters.

```
string f(char[][]s){int i=0;foreach(var x in s)for(i=0;x[i]!=35;i++)if(x[i]!=32)s[0][i]=x[i];return new string(s[0],0,i);}
```

157 bytes:

```
string g(char[][]s){var o=new char[s[0].Length];foreach(var x in s)for(int i=0;x[i]!=35;i++)if(x[i]!=32|o[i]<1)o[i]=x[i];return new string(o).TrimEnd('\0');}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Trim()` work instead of `TrimEnd()`? Even better, I think you can save a lot of bytes by using s[0] as the output var and using `return new string(s[0],0,i)` where `i` is the index of the last code character. That idea may require two `for` loops instead of the `foreach`, I'll think about it more and try to write actual code later today.

Comment: `Trim()` will trim from the start as well, which I believe wouldn't be valid. I also was originally doing the loading into s[0] and I had int `i;` outside of the loop (to reuse it in the return) which I believe ultimately added bytes

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 126 bytes

```
:a;N;$!ba;s,#[^\n]*\n,#,g;s,^,#,;:;/#[^ ]/{/^# /s,^# *,,;t;H;s,#.,#,g}
t;/#[^ ]/!{H;s,#.,#,g};t;g;s,\n#(.)[^\n]*,\1,g;s,...$,,
```

Requires a newline at the end of the input.
I'm sure I can golf this a little more, but I'm just happy it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
PhceCSMCQ\#
```

A program that takes input of a list of strings on STDIN and prints a string.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=PhceCSMCQ%5C%23&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%27hello+++++++++%23Line+one%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++%23Line+two%27%2C+%27+++++++world%21+%23Line+three%27%5D%0A%5B%27E+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23This+comment+intentionally+left+blank%27%2C+%27+ac+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27+++h+s++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++ecti++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++++on+is+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++one+c+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27+++++++++++++++++++++haracte++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++++r+longer++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++than+the+++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++last%21+%23%27%5D%0A%5B%274++++++++++%23This+number+is+7%27%2C+%27+8+++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++15+++++++%23That+last+comment+is+wrong.%27%2C+%27++++16+++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++23+++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++42+%23%27%5D%0A%5B%27Hello+++++++++++++++++++++%23Comment+1%27%2C+%27++++++world+++++++++++++++%23Comment+2%27%2C+%27+++++++++++%2C++++++++++++++%23Comment+3%27%2C+%27+++++++++++++how++++++++++%23Comment+4%27%2C+%27+++++++++++++++++are++++++%23Comment+5%27%2C+%27+++++++++++++++++++++you%3F+%23Comment+6%27%5D%0A%5B%27Prepare+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++for...++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++++++++++extra+spaces%21+%23%27%5D&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
PhceCSMCQ\#  Program. Input: Q
       CQ    Transpose Q
     SM      Sort each element of that lexicographically
    C        Transpose that
   e         Yield the last element of that, giving the program ending with ' #' and some
             parts of the comments
  c      \#  Split that on the character '#'
 h           Yield the first element of that, giving the program with a trailing space
P            All but the last element of that, removing the trailing space
             Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 39 bytes

```
{[Zmax](@_».comb).join.split(' #')[0]}
```

Translation of the [Python solution by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93072/14880).
Takes input as a list of strings, and returns a string.

([try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/eifhpqhiu3))

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
żḟ€” ;€” Ḣ€
i€”#’©ḣ@"ç/ḣ®ṪṖ
```

Test it at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzhuJ_igqzigJ0gO-KCrOKAnSDhuKLigqwKaeKCrOKAnSPigJnCqeG4o0Aiw6cv4bijwq7huarhuZY&input=&args=IlByZXBhcmUgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIyBjb21tZW50IDEiLCIgICAgICAgIGZvci4uLiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMgY29tbWVudCAyIiwiICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZXh0cmEgc3BhY2VzISAjIGNvbW1lbnQgMyI)**

Uses the strictest spec - the extra space before the comment character is removed at the cost of a byte.

Input is a list of strings.

Comment: @Erik the Golfer - maybe so, but did you see the crushing he gave me [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93068/53748)?

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, <s>216</s> 175 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)=
'hello         #Line one
              #Line two
       world! #Line three'

DECLARE @i INT=1,@j INT=0WHILE @i<LEN(@)SELECT @=stuff(@,@j+1,len(x),x),@j=iif(x=char(10),0,@j+1),@i+=1FROM(SELECT ltrim(substring(@,@i,1))x)x PRINT LEFT(@,patindex('%_#%',@))
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)=
'hello         #Line one
              #Line two
       world! #Line three'

DECLARE @i INT=1,@j INT=0
WHILE @i<LEN(@)
  SELECT @=stuff(@,@j+1,len(x),x),@j=iif(x=char(10),0,@j+1),@i+=1
  FROM(SELECT ltrim(substring(@,@i,1))x)x
PRINT LEFT(@,patindex('%_#%',@))
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/539127/parse-the-comments-out-of-my-esoteric-code)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

[Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93068/43319).

```apl
(⎕UCS¯2↓⍳∘35↑⊢)⌈⌿∘⎕UCS
```

`(`

`⎕UCS` character representation of

`¯2↓` all but the last two of

`⍳∘35↑` up until the position of the first 35 ("#"), in that which is outside the parenthesis, taken from

`⊢` that which is outside the parenthesis

`)` namely...

`⌈⌿` the columnar maximums

`∘` of

`⎕UCS` the Unicode values

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%28%u2395UCS%AF2%u2193%u2373%u221835%u2191%u22A2%29%u2308%u233F%u2218%u2395UCS%20%u22C4%20%u22A2Input%u2190%u2191%27hello%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23Line%20one%27%20%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23Line%20two%27%20%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20world%21%20%23Line%20three%27%20%u22C4%20f%20Input&run)

Comment: How many bytes?

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 77 bytes

```
puts File.readlines("stack.txt").join('').gsub(/\s{1}#.*\n/,'').gsub(/\s/,'')
```

Comment: Hardcoding an input filename is not an acceptable method of input.

Comment: @Mego, where can I find the rules of what's "acceptable"?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/45941